# Does Haskell have tail-recursive optimization?

Tags: haskell, optimization, lazy-evaluation, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I discovered the "time" command in unix today and thought I'd use it to check the difference in runtimes between tail-recursive and normal recursive functions in Haskell.

I wrote the following functions:

```
--tail recursive
fac :: (Integral a) => a -> a
fac x = fac' x 1 where
    fac' 1 y = y
    fac' x y = fac' (x-1) (x*y) 

--normal recursive
facSlow :: (Integral a) => a -> a
facSlow 1 = 1
facSlow x = x * facSlow (x-1)
```

These are valid keeping in mind they were solely for use with this project, so I didn't bother to check for zeroes or negative numbers.

However, upon writing a main method for each, compiling them, and running them with the "time" command, both had similar runtimes with the *normal* recursive function edging out the tail recursive one. This is contrary to what I'd heard with regards to tail-recursive optimization in lisp. What's the reason for this?

Comment: I believe that TCO is an optimization to save some call stack, it does not imply that you'll save some CPU time. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Haven't tested it with lisp, but the tutorial I read implied that setting up the stack incurred more processor costs in itself, whereas the compiled-to-iterative tail-recursive solution didn't expend any energy (time) doing this and thus was more efficient.

Comment: @Jerome well it depends on a lot of things, but typically caches also come into play, so TCO will usually produce a faster program as well..

Comment: What's the reason for this? In a word: laziness.

Comment: Interestingly, your `fac` is more-or-less how ghc calculates `product [n,n-1..1]` using an auxilliary function `prod`, but of course `product [1..n]` would be simpler. I can only assume they haven't made it strict in its second argument on the grounds that this is the sort of thing ghc is very confident it can compile down to a simple accumulator.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Haskell uses lazy-evaluation to implement recursion, so treats anything as a promise to provide a value when needed (this is called a thunk). Thunks get reduced only as much as necessary to proceed, no more. This resembles the way you simplify an expression mathematically, so it's helpful to think of it that way. The fact that evaluation order is *not* specified by your code allows the compiler to do lots of even cleverer optimisations than just the tail-call elimination youre used to. **Compile with `-O2` if you want optimisation!**

Let's see how we evaluate `facSlow 5` as a case study:

```
facSlow 5
5 * facSlow 4            -- Note that the `5-1` only got evaluated to 4
5 * (4 * facSlow 3)       -- because it has to be checked against 1 to see
5 * (4 * (3 * facSlow 2))  -- which definition of `facSlow` to apply.
5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * facSlow 1)))
5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * 1)))
5 * (4 * (3 * 2))
5 * (4 * 6)
5 * 24
120
```

So just as you worried, we have a build-up of numbers before any calculations happen, but *unlike* you worried, there's no stack of `facSlow` function calls hanging around waiting to terminate - each reduction is applied and goes away, leaving a [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) in its wake (that is because `(*)` is strict and so triggers the evaluation of its second argument).

Haskell's recursive functions aren't evaluated in a very recursive way! The only stack of calls hanging around are the multiplications themselves. If  `(*)` is viewed as a strict data constructor, this is what's known as *guarded* recursion (although it is usually referred to as such with *non*-strict data constructors, where what's left in its wake are the data constructors - when forced by further access).

Now let's look at the tail-recursive `fac 5`:

```
fac 5
fac' 5 1
fac' 4 {5*1}       -- Note that the `5-1` only got evaluated to 4
fac' 3 {4*{5*1}}    -- because it has to be checked against 1 to see
fac' 2 {3*{4*{5*1}}} -- which definition of `fac'` to apply.
fac' 1 {2*{3*{4*{5*1}}}}
{2*{3*{4*{5*1}}}}        -- the thunk "{...}" 
(2*{3*{4*{5*1}}})        -- is retraced 
(2*(3*{4*{5*1}}))        -- to create
(2*(3*(4*{5*1})))        -- the computation
(2*(3*(4*(5*1))))        -- on the stack
(2*(3*(4*5)))
(2*(3*20))
(2*60)
120
```

So you can see how the tail recursion by itself hasn't saved you any time or space. Not only does it take more steps overall than `facSlow 5`, it also builds a nested thunk (shown here as `{...}`) - needing an *extra space* for it - which describes the future computation, the nested multiplications to be performed.

This thunk is then unraveled by traversing *it* to the bottom, recreating the computation on the stack. There is also a danger here of causing stack overflow with very long computations, for both versions.

If we want to hand-optimise this, all we need to do is make it strict. You could use the strict application operator `$!` to define

```
facSlim :: (Integral a) => a -> a
facSlim x = facS' x 1 where
    facS' 1 y = y
    facS' x y = facS' (x-1) $! (x*y)
```

This forces `facS'` to be strict in its second argument. (It's already strict in its first argument because that has to be evaluated to decide which definition of `facS'` to apply.)

Sometimes strictness can help enormously, sometimes it's a big mistake because laziness is more efficient. Here it's a good idea:

```
facSlim 5
facS' 5 1
facS' 4 5 
facS' 3 20
facS' 2 60
facS' 1 120
120
```

Which is what you wanted to achieve I think.

### Summary

- If you want to optimise your code, step one is to compile with `-O2`
- Tail recursion is only good when there's no thunk build-up, and adding strictness usually helps to prevent it, if and where appropriate. This happens when you're building a result that is needed later on all at once.
- Sometimes tail recursion is a bad plan and guarded recursion is a better fit, i.e. when the result you're building will be needed bit by bit, in portions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429634/foldl-is-tail-recursive-so-how-come-foldr-runs-faster-than-foldl) about `foldr` and `foldl` for example, and test them against each other.

Try these two:

```
length $ foldl1 (++) $ replicate 1000 
    "The size of intermediate expressions is more important than tail recursion."
length $ foldr1 (++) $ replicate 1000 
    "The number of reductions performed is more important than tail recursion!!!"
```

`foldl1` is tail recursive, whereas `foldr1` performs guarded recursion so that the first item is immediately presented for further processing/access. <sub>(The first "parenthesizes" to the left at once, `(...((s+s)+s)+...)+s`, forcing its input list fully to its end and building a big thunk of future computation much sooner than its full results are needed; the second parenthesizes to the right gradually, `s+(s+(...+(s+s)...))`, consuming the input list bit by bit, so the whole thing is able to operate in constant space, with optimizations).</sub>

You might need to adjust the number of zeros depending on what hardware you're using.

Comment: @WillNess That's excellent, thanks. no need for retracting. I think it's a better answer for posterity now.

Comment: This is great, but may I suggest a nod to [strictness analysis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictness_analysis)? I think that will almost certainly do the job for the tail-recursive factorial in any reasonably recent version of GHC.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you so much for taking the time to write this up! Studying functional languages for a class, and I've been confused about tail recursion. This really helped.

Answer (score 18):

It should be mentioned that the `fac` function is not a good candidate for guarded recursion. Tail recursion is the way to go here. Due to laziness you are not getting the effect of TCO in your `fac'` function because the accumulator arguments keep building large thunks, which when evaluated will require a huge stack. To prevent this and get the desired effect of TCO you need to make these accumulator arguments strict.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

fac :: (Integral a) => a -> a
fac x = fac' x 1 where
  fac' 1  y = y
  fac' x !y = fac' (x-1) (x*y)
```

If you compile using `-O2` (or just `-O`) GHC will probably do this on its own in the [strictness analysis](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness#Strictness_analysis) phase.

Comment: I think it's clearer with `$!` than with `BangPatterns`, but this is a good answer.  Especially the mention of strictness analysis.

Answer (score 9):

You should check out the wiki article on [tail recursion in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion).  In particular, because of expression evaluation, the kind of recursion you want is *guarded* recursion.  If you work out the details of what's going on under the hood (in the abstract machine for Haskell) you get the same kind of thing as with tail recursion in strict languages.  Along with this, you have a uniform syntax for lazy functions (tail recursion will tie you to strict evaluation, whereas guarded recursion works more naturally).

(And in learning Haskell, the rest of those wiki pages are awesome, too!)

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly, GHC automatically optimizes plain recursive functions into tail-recursive optimized ones.