# Haskell non-tail recursion

Tags: haskell

I want to know if this represents a tail-recursion. And if it isn't how can I do it.

```
 countP :: [a] -> (a->Bool) -> Int
 countP [] _ = 0
 countP (x:xs) p = countP_aux (x:xs) p 0

 countP_aux [] _ _ = 0
 countP_aux (x:xs) p acumul
                        |p x==True = (countP_aux xs p (acumul))+1
                        |otherwise = (countP_aux xs p (acumul))

  countP [1,2,3] (>0)
  3
  (72 reductions, 95 cells)
```

This exercise show how many values in a list are verified by p condition.
Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble with double-negations - "if it isn't a non-tail recursion" means what? BTW. I would think that "countP [] f" should always return 0. Your code fails instead.

Comment: I want to know if it represents a tail-recursion. Post edited

Comment: Why does it matter if it's a tail recursion?

Comment: Tail recursion has a better performance than non-tail recursion

Comment: @tomss Not in the presence of lazy evaluation. (Tail recursion is faster in strict languages, but Haskell is non-strict.) You should read [this question about tail recursive optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization).

Comment: (p x) == True, in your guard should be simplified by (p x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not tail recursive because of

```
(countP_aux xs p (acumul))+1
```

Tail calls should return the result of the recursive call, rather than doing calculation with the result of the recursive call.

You can convert a non-tail recursive function to be tail-recursive by using an accumulator where you perform the additional work, i.e.

Say you have a simple counting function

```
f a
  | a < 1 = 0 
  | otherwise = f (a-1) + 1
```

You can make it tail recursive like so:

```
f' acc a = 
  | a < 1 = acc 
  | otherwise = f' (acc + 1) (a-1)
f = f' 0
```

Comment: And how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: might be nice to refactor to `f' acc a` and then let `f = f' 0`

Comment: Also might be nice to seq the accumulator.

Comment: ..because then you don't build up a big stack of unevaluated thunks.

Comment: ghc can probably figure that out on its own, can't it? the given thing _is_ tail recursive, the lazy accumulator issue is something else.