# Haskell take sum recursively

Tags: haskell

Hello I want to take a sum of functions call in Haskel but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. To be more specific, I have a function f(a,b,c)=a+b+c and I want to take an int like this:

x=Sum( from i=0 to i=c) f(1,1,i)

so far I have written this, but it doesn't even compile. Can you help me?

```
f a b c = a+b+c

my_sum f a b c+1 =f a b c+1 + my_sum f a b c
```

I get `parse error in pattern my_sum`

eg for `my_sum f 1 1 5` the result would be f(1,1,5)+f(1,1,4)+f(1,1,3)+f(1,1,2)+f(1,1,1)

I dont want to use lists

Comment: I don't understand your issue at all, can you reword?

Comment: your example corresponds to `Sum( from i=1 to i=c) f(1,1,i)`, not `i=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the `c+1` on the left side of a definition.  Since you're just summing, it doesn't matter if you count up from 0 to `c` or count down from `c` to 0, so you could instead do

```
my_sum f a b 0 = f a b 0
my_sum f a b c = f a b c + my_sum f a b (c - 1)
```

Then you could use it as

```
> let g x y z = x + y + z
> my_sum g 0 0 10
55
```

---

Some more detail on why your code failed to compile: Whenever you have a pattern on the left side of a definition, such as

```
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

You can only match on *constructors*, *names* (like `n` or `c`), and *literals* (which are essentially constructors for the basic types).  The function `+` is not a constructor, it is a function belonging to the `Num` typeclass, so therefore you can not pattern match on it.  You may be confused from seeing list pattern matching before because it uses an operator:

```
myListSum [] = 0
myListSum (x:xs) = x + myListSum xs
```

but in fact, `:` is the `Cons` constructor for lists, and `[]` is the empty list constructor.  You can think of the list type defined as

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Or, if you were to replace all the symbols with words

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

although its a bit different in reality since there's more that goes into defining lists, but that's the basic idea.  This means that a pattern like

```
f [] = ...
f (x:xs) = ...
```

Is equivalent to

```
f Empty = ...
f (Cons x xs) = ...
```

just with more convenient syntax.

However, `Int` can be though of as a very large ADT defined as

```
data Int = -2147483648 | -2147483647 | ... | -1 | 0 | 1 | ... | 2147483646 | 2147483647
```

where each number itself is a different constructor.   Then you can match on any individual number, but not anything like `(x + 1)` or `(x * 2)`, because `+` and `*` are not constructors, just regular functions.  (Note: `Int` is not actually defined this way because that would be really inefficient, it's defined at a more primitive level)

Answer (score 2):

**`n+k` patterns are bad**

Your code:

```
my_sum f a b c+1 =f a b c+1 + my_sum f a b c
```

includes a pattern in the form `c+1` which A) should have parentheses B) Needs a base case (I assume you want to stop when `c == 0`) and C) is a syntactic form that has been removed from the language.

Instead, explicitly subtract 1 from `c` when you want and be sure to handle the base case:

```
my_sum f a b 0 = f a b 0
my_sum f a b n = f a b n + my_sum f a b (n-1)
```

This also has a memory leak meaning it will build up a large computation in the form `f1 + (f a b n' + (f a b n'' + (f a b n''' + (...`.  You can handle the leak by using an accumulator or a higher level function and optimization at compile-time.

**A cleaner Solution**

List comprehension strikes me as the most reasonable solution here:

```
sum [f a b i | i <- [0..c] ]
```

The sum of the function `f` applied to arugments `a`, `b` and finally `i` where `i` ranges from `0` to `c` inclusively.

Comment: Thx for you answer but I dont want to use lists

Comment: Because it's too easy and I dont care about doing it efficiently. I am more interested in learning how to use recursion

Answer (score 0):

You can get from list formulations to the non-list, recursive formulations, with manual  inlining and fusing of the functions in play:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.List

f a b c   = a+b+c
g f a b c = sum . map (f a b) $ [0..c]
          = foldl' (\ !x y -> x + f a b y) 0 $ enumFromTo 0 c
          = h 0 0   where
              h !acc i | i > c     = acc
                       | otherwise = h (acc + f a b i) (i+1)
```

Strictness annotations prevent uncontrolled [build-up of thunks and stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052612/849891) for big values of `c`.