# Why does Haskell's foldr NOT stackoverflow while the same Scala implementation does?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, fold

I am reading [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/).

Exercise 3.10 says that `foldRight` overflows (See images below).
As far as I know , however `foldr` in Haskell does not.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/

```
-- if the list is empty, the result is the initial value z; else
-- apply f to the first element and the result of folding the rest
foldr f z []     = z 
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs) 

-- if the list is empty, the result is the initial value; else
-- we recurse immediately, making the new initial value the result
-- of combining the old initial value with the first element.
foldl f z []     = z                  
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

How is this different behaviour possible?

What is the difference between the two languages/compilers that cause this different behaviour?

Where does this difference come from ? The platform ? The language?  The compiler?

Is it possible to write a stack-safe foldRight in Scala? If yes, how?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `foldr` in Haskell isn't tail-recursive, so it's still prone to stack overflow errors. What's different in Haskell is the lazy evaluation semantics, which sometimes allows `foldr` to not evaluate *both* arguments of the folding operator. More details here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow

Comment: Also, Scala's built-in `foldRight` method is not prone to stack overflows (anymore), since it calls `foldLeft` on the reversed list, and `foldLeft` isn't even recursive. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L396-L397 https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L105-L114

Comment: Ticket for old Scala's old `foldRight`: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3295

Comment: In Scala `foldRight` and `foldLeft` are strict. In Haskell `foldr'` and `foldl'` are strict too. But in Haskell `foldr` and `foldl` are lazy.
So, `foldRight`, `foldr'` and `foldl` could overflows.

Comment: @viorior, Haskell doesn't have `foldr'` in `Prelude` or in `Data.List`, because it's simply not useful—passing a function to `foldr` that's strict in its second argument gets you strict behavior (that could overflow the stack if the list is long).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Haskell is lazy. The definition

```
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

tells us that the behaviour of `foldr f z xs` with a non-empty list `xs` is determined by the *laziness* of the combining function `f`.

In particular the call `foldr f z (x:xs)` allocates just one thunk on the heap, *`{foldr f z xs}`* (writing *`{...}`* for a thunk holding an expression `...`), and calls `f` with two arguments - `x` and the thunk. What happens next, is `f`'s responsibility.

In particular, if it's a lazy data constructor (like e.g. `(:)`), it will immediately be returned to the caller of the `foldr` call (with the constructor's two slots filled by (references to) the two values).

And if `f` does demand its value on the right, with minimal compiler optimizations no thunks should be created at all (or one, at the most - the current one), as the value of `foldr f z xs` is immediately needed and the usual stack-based evaluation can used:

```
foldr f z [a,b,c,....,n] ==
    a `f` (b `f` (c `f` (... (n `f` z)...)))
```

So `foldr` can indeed cause SO, when used with strict combining function on extremely long input lists. But if the combining function doesn't demand right away its value on the right, or only demands a part of it, the evaluation will be suspended in a thunk, and the partial result as created by `f` will be immediately returned. Same with the argument on the left, but they already come as thunks, potentially, in the input list.

Comment: Dear Will, thank you for the detailed answer! Could you please give a specific example where foldr causes SO ? I don't understand how the laziness of `f` can change? Could you give an example for a lazy `f` and for a not lazy `f` and explain why one is more lazy than the other?

Comment: `foldr (+) 0 [1..100000000000]`. because `(+)` is strict. but `foldr (:) [] [1..100000000000]` will just return `1 : {foldr (:) [] [2..100000000000]}`, because `(:)` is  a lazy data constructor (it doesn't demand full value of its arguments, and just stores pointers to suspensions of future computations in its two fields, `head` and `tail` (or `car` and `cdr` in Lisp)).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have one more question, what does thunk mean ? This is the first time I hear this term .

Comment: imagine a record which holds: a. a Boolean, `has_value?`, initially set to `False`; b. a lambda function of no arguments, or any other means of representing a future computation, that can be called to get that value; and c. a place to store the value after it was calculated. That is a thunk, conceptually.

Comment: So your example `foldr (+) 0 [1..10000000000]` does cause SO but  `foldl (+) 0 [1..10000000000]` won't cause SO ? Is that correct?

Comment: `foldl (+) 0 [1..10000000000]` will cause SO in another way. there is a good answer about this; I'll search  for a link in a moment. here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13052612/849891 (and you're welcome :))

Comment: "thunk" is a ["dialect past and past participle of think"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thunk). i.e. an expression is not evaluated until it is needed for the first time, and then it *does* get evaluated and its result value is stored - so the next time it is needed we won't have to "think" about it, it will have been already "thunk". or so the story goes.

Answer (score 19):

Haskell is lazy. So `foldr` allocates on the heap, not the stack. Depending on the strictness of the argument function, it may allocate a single (small) result, or a large structure.

You're still losing space, compared to a strict, tail-recursive implementation, but it doesn't look as obvious, since you've traded stack for heap.

Comment: Consider the recursive `go` in `foldr`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#foldr . `go` returns an suspension on the heap.

Comment: I've clarified, as it shouldn't be confused with the simple `foldl (+)` laziness heap space leak. `foldr` can run in constant space if `k` is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the authors here are not referring to any foldRight definition in the scala standard library, such as the one defined on List. They are referring to the definition of foldRight they gave above in section 3.4.

The scala standard library defines the foldRight in terms of foldLeft by reversing the list (which can be done in constant stack space) then calling foldLeft with the the arguments of the passed function reversed.  This works for lists, but won't work for a structure which cannot be safely reversed, for example:

```
scala> Stream.continually(false)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Boolean] = Stream(false, ?)

scala> res0.reverse
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Now lets think about what *should* be the result of this operation:

```
Stream.continually(false).foldRight(true)(_ && _)
```

The answer should be false, it doesn't matter how many false values are in the stream or if it is infinite, if we are going to combine them with a conjunction, the result will be false.

haskell of course gets this with no problem:

```
Prelude> foldr (&&) True (repeat False)
False
```

And that is because of two important things: haskell's foldr will traverse the stream from left to right, not right to left, and haskell is lazy by default.  The first item here, that foldr actually traverses the list from left to right might surprise or confuse some people who think of a right fold as starting from the right, but the important feature of a right fold is not which end of a structure it starts on, but in which direction the associativity is.  So give a list [1,2,3,4] and an op named `op`, a left fold is

```
((1 op 2) op 3) op 4)
```

and a right fold is

```
(1 op (2 op (3 op 4)))
```

But the order of evaluation shouldn't matter. So what the authors have done here in chapter 3 is to give you a fold which traverses the list from left to right, but because scala is by default strict, we still will not be able to traverse our stream of infinite falses, but have some patience, they will get to that in chapter 5 :)  I'll give you a sneak peek, lets look at the difference between foldRight as it is defined in the standard library and as it is defined in the Foldable typeclass in scalaz:

Here's the implementation from the scala standard library:

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B
```

Here's the definition from scalaz's Foldable:

```
def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B
```

The difference is that the Bs are all lazy, and now we get to fold our infinite stream again, as long as we give a function which is sufficiently lazy in its second parameter:

```
scala> Foldable[Stream].foldRight(Stream.continually(false),true)(_ && _)
res0: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 4):

One easy way to demonstrate this in Haskell is to use **equational reasoning** to demonstrate lazy evaluation.  Let's write the `find` function in terms of `foldr`:

```
-- Return the first element of the list that satisfies the predicate, or `Nothing`.
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find p = foldr (step p) Nothing 
    where step pred x next = if pred x then Just x else next

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z []     = z 
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

In an eager language, if you wrote `find` with `foldr` it would traverse the whole list and use O(n) space.  With lazy evaluation, it stops at the first element that satisfies the predicate, and uses only O(1) space (modulo garbage collection):

```
find odd [0..]
    == foldr (step odd) Nothing [0..]
    == step odd 0 (foldr (step odd) Nothing [1..])
    == if odd 0 then Just 0 else (foldr (step odd) Nothing [1..])
    == if False then Just 0 else (foldr (step odd) Nothing [1..])
    == foldr (step odd) Nothing [1..]
    == step odd 1 (foldr (step odd) Nothing [2..])
    == if odd 1 then Just 1 else (foldr (step odd) Nothing [2..])
    == if True then Just 1 else (foldr (step odd) Nothing [2..])
    == Just 1
```

This evaluation stops in a finite number of steps, in spite of the fact that the list `[0..]` is infinite, so we know that we're not traversing the whole list.  In addition, there is an upper bound on the complexity of the expressions at each step, which translates into a constant upper bound on the memory required to evaluate this.

The key here is that the `step` function that we're folding with has this property: no matter what the values of `x` and `next` are, it will either:

1. Evaluate to `Just x`, without invoking the `next` thunk, or
2. Tail-call the `next` thunk (in effect, if not literally).