# Does every Haskell function do tail calls?

Tags: haskell, recursion, operators, call, tail-call

I wondered that every function in Haskell should be tail recursive.

The factorial function implemented as a non tail recursive function:

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
```

Every operator is a function too, so this is equivalent to

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = (*) n (fact (n - 1))
```

But this is clearly a tail call to me. I wonder why this code causes stack overflows if every call just creates a new thunk on the heap. Shouldn't i get a heap overflow?

Comment: It can only a be a tail call if the function call is in the tail position.

Comment: Oh. You're right. GHC rewrites the pattern matching to case expressions. But even there it could be possible to do a tail call because the call is in the last place in the function

Comment: Tail call /= tail recursive.

Comment: There is indeed a tail call.  The `fact` function will tail call the `(*)` function.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = (*) n (fact (n - 1))
```

the last `(*) ...` is a tail call, as you observed. The last argument `fact (n-1)` however will build a thunk which is immediately demanded by `(*)`. This leads to a non-tail call to `fact`. Recursively, this will consume the stack.

TL;DR: the posted code performs a tail call, but `(*)` does not.

(Also "the stack" in Haskell is a not so clear notion as in strict languages. Some implementations of Haskell use something more complex than that. You can search for "push/enter vs eval/apply" strategies if you want some gory details.)

Comment: So it's the nature of the `(+)` operator. Maybe the `(+)` implementation keeps the value on the stack and that's why i get a stack overflow and not a heap overflow

Comment: @dosenfrucht, thinking about tail calls in Haskell may lead you astray, because Haskell's evaluation model is very different from Scheme's or ML's. However, the fact that `*` is strict in its second argument means that you will face the same problem as a result of `fact (n-1)` not being in tail position as you would in a strict language.