# Are the Haskell options for Tail Call Optimisation indicative of the Spineless Tagless Graph-Machine?

Tags: haskell, recursion, optimization, spineless-tagless-graph

One of the amazing things about [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) is the [Spineless Tagless Graph Machine](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:VE05oXnwu4AJ:research.microsoft.com/jump/67083+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au) (STG). At the time, (according to [SPJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Peyton_Jones)) it was written to [enable the laziness that enabled functional programming to work on the limited hardware of the time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmjvOLlCdFU). Subsequently it has been shown to [have any additional benefits for functional programming](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf).

When we see languages like [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) - [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) features prominently (as it does in Haskell). Part of what makes this [particularly effective](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailCallOptimization) is the feature known as [Tail Call Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). The reason you want Tail Call Elimination is because if a function calls itself 1000's of times, it can blow the stack, even stackoverflow. [sic]

Now [Haskell has some interesting options](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/GHC#Use_optimisation) for [Tail Call Elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization). What [we see is that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052612/15441):

> Haskell's recursive functions aren't evaluated in a very recursive way! The only stack of calls hanging around are the multiplications themselves. If  (*) is viewed as a strict data constructor, this is what's known as guarded recursion (although it is usually referred to as such with non-strict data constructors, where what's left in its wake are the data constructors - when forced by further access).

My question is: **Are the Haskell options for Tail Call Optimisation indicative of the Spineless Tagless Graph-machine?**

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but GHC moved from the push/enter evaluation model to the eval/apply one a few years ago because the latter started to become more performant. This changed the calling conventions significantly. I have no precise idea about whether TCO is used right now in GHC, though.

Comment: Of course TCO is still used.

Comment: Thanks @chi - could expand on the implications of that change?

Comment: I can't really recommend anything but checking the [Making a fast curry](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/evalapplyjfp06.pdf) paper, and possibly a few more...

Comment: Cool - can you expand that into an answer?