# How does argument passing order affect lazy evaluation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation

I've been trying to understand lazy evaluation in Haskell and I understood it basically as only evaluate when you have to. But when trying to implement fibonacci efficiently I came across this (weird?) behaviour:
This Implementation:

```
--wrapper function used by both implementations
fib :: Int -> Int
fib x = if x < 0 then 0 else fib2 0 1 x

fib2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
fib2 x y 0 = x
fib2 x y z = fib2 y (x + y) (z - 1)
```

will work even when called with

```
fib 20000000
> -70318061090422843
```

while swapping the passed arguments in the recursive call:

```
fib2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
fib2 x y 0 = x
fib2 x y z = fib2 (x + y) x (z - 1)
```

results in:

```
fib 20000000
>*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Why don't I have to tell the compiler to eagerly evaluate in the first example?
Why does the second example not work while the first does?

I used the GHCi 8.0.1 on Windows 10 for this.

Comment: not sure about this case (probably the first version gets unrolled to basically a loop while the second keeps allocating stack frames) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization for a similar case...

Comment: I have a feeling it must be related to currying, as the overflow example builds up the thunks in the first argument.

Comment: Please include ghci version information. For me this doesn't happen, but allocation fails instead (7.6.3).

Comment: well in my case both are already TCO aren't they? and in those answers it even specifically says to make the accumulation argument strict, which I do not for the first example and it still works. That's practically the root of my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, notice that the difference between your two versions is quantitative, not qualitative. The first will stack overflow on an input of `40000000`, and the second will complete successfully on an input of `10000000`. It looks like the second version uses twice as much stack as the first.

Basically, the reason is that, if we introduce the notation `{n}` for the thunks that live in the `x` and `y` arguments, your first version does

```
fib2 {n} {n+1} 0 = {n}
fib2 {n} {n+1} z = let {n+2} = (+) {n} {n+1}    -- build a thunk
                    in fib2 {n+1} {n+2} (z - 1)
```

while the second version does

```
fib2 {n+1} {n} 0 = {n+1}
fib2 {n+1} {n} z = let {n+2} = (+) {n+1} {n}    -- build a thunk
                    in fib2 {n+2} {n+1} (z - 1)
```

Now consider what happens when the `fib2` recursion finishes and it's time to evaluate `{n}` (or `{n+1}`; let's just ignore this difference). Each of the thunks `{0}`, ..., `{n}` will get evaluated just once, in some order. It happens that `(+)` evaluates its left argument first, then its right argument. For definiteness, let's just take `n = 6`. The evaluation looks like

```
{6} = (+) {4} {5}
... {4} = (+) {2} {3}
... ... {2} = (+) {0} {1}
... ... ... {0} = 0
... ... ... {1} = 1
... ... {2} = 1
... ... {3} = (+) {1} {2}
... ... ... {1} = 1
... ... ... {2} = 1   -- we already calculated it
... ... {3} = 2
... {4} = 3
... {5} = ......
```

The stack will never get deeper than `n/2` levels, since we recurse from `{n}` to `{n-2}` first and when we need to compute `{n-1}` we have already computed `{n-2}`.

In contrast, in the second version we recurse from `{n}` to `{n-1}` first, so the stack will have `n` levels.

Comment: Yes, makes 100% sense, so one big number was not enough to test it :P