# Is this tail-recursive? New edge cases

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Branch Tree Tree

sumt (Leaf i) acc = i + acc
sumt (Branch l r) acc = sumt l (sumt r acc)
```

`sumt` is in tail position, but it's also in the accumulator. I lean towards no because it has to evaluate the inner call to `sumt` (using a call stack), but I can see why it could be tail-recursive because the last function call is `sumt`. `fibsumt` is clearly tail-recursive even though the acc function creates a deep call-stack.

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 2) + fib (n - 1)

fibsumt 0 acc = acc
fibsumt n acc = fibsumt (n - 1) (acc + (fib n))
```

Is `sumt` classified as a tail-recursive function?

Comment: I don’t think so, since the result of the inner call to `fibsumt` must then be added to the accumulator.

Comment: … things are different in Haskell though, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization

Comment: I probably should have used a strict language for this because laziness makes this all a bit more difficult.

Comment: Yeah, in a strict one that would not qualify because of the outer add... but you could move it inside the inner recursive call, couldn’t you? Where is that `b` coming from?

Comment: @RegisKuckaertz That answer is a good read but I don't think it quite applies here since `sumt` is strict in both of its arguments.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I would have thought that because the recursive call does not inspect `acc`, then the compiler would box the value. Is that reasoning incorrect?

Comment: “Strict” in this context is quite a specific term: _how much of the input is forced when evaluating the output to WHNF?_ It should be clear that `(+)` (on `Int`s) is strict in both of its arguments, so `sumt` (which calls `(+)`) is also strict. GHC _may_ implement the recursive calls using the trampoline-esque evaluation strategy described in the linked answer but with optimisations on it won’t. (Disclaimer: I haven’t looked at the generated Core so I might be talking outta my ass!)

Comment: haha, no that's very useful, thank you.