# Haskell's foldr/l and Clojure's reduce

Tags: haskell, clojure, stack-overflow, reduce, fold

I decided to get serious with Haskell, and am wrapping my head around the use of **foldl** and **foldr**. They really feel a lot like Clojure's **reduce** - but I might be wrong, and ran into a problem soon enough, which I hope someone will easily explain.

Working with this doc:
https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'

Before getting too deep into implementing my own versions of foldr/foldl, I decided to first test the existing ones from Prelude:

```
± |master U:2 ✗| → ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/akarpov/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> foldr (+) 0 [1..9999999]
49999995000000
Prelude> foldr (+) 0 [1..99999999]
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Didn't see that coming (same result when using foldl); I rather expected something along the lines of Clojure:

```
> (time (reduce +' (range 1 99999999)))
"Elapsed time: 3435.638258 msecs"
4999999850000001
```

The only obvious (and irrelevant) difference is using +' rather than +, but it's only to accommodate the JVM's type system - the number produced doesn't fit into a [default] Long, and +' will automatically use a BigInteger when needed. Most importantly, no stack overflow.
It seems to indicate, therefore, that folding/reduction in Haskell/Clojure is either implemented very differently, or my use of haskell's implementation is wrong.

in case it is relevant, these are global-project settings:
- packages: []
- resolver: lts-13.8

Comment: Use `Data.List.foldl'`, the strict form of `foldl`.

Comment: Haskell equivalent to Clojure's `(reduce +' (range 1 99999999))` is `foldl' (+) 0 [1..99999998]` (sic) (apparently; to get the same result as you show). Haskell ranges are inclusive.

Comment: see also [Does Haskell have tail-recursive optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042353/849891). the question is worded differently, but it is actually near-duplicate for this one -- `foldl` is tail-recursive, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Problem

As [the Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'.) explains, the function `(+)` is strict in both its arguments, which means that when you try to do `1 + (2 + 3)`, you first need to calculate `(2 + 3)`. While this may not seem like a big problem at first, it becomes when you have a long list. Quoting the wiki,

> to evaluate:
>          `1 + (2 + (3 + (4 + (...))))`, 1 is pushed on the stack.
>
> Then: `2 + (3 + (4 + (...)))` is evaluated. So 2 is pushed on the stack.
>
> Then: `3 + (4 + (...))` is evaluated. So 3 is pushed on the stack.
>
> Then: `4 + (...)` is evaluated. So 4 is pushed on the stack.
>
> Then: your limited stack will eventually run full when you evaluate a large enough chain of (+)s. This then triggers the stack overflow exception.

I don't much about Clojure, but if `(+')` works, then it definitely does not need both its arguments to be evaluated before being reduced, and that is also the solution in Haskell.

## Solution

Foldl would not solve the problem, as it is known that foldl has to travel the whole list twice before returning a result --which is not efficient--, and even then `(+)` is still strict, so the reducible expressions are not reduced.

To solve this, you must use a non-strict function. In the standard Prelude, `seq :: a -> b -> b` can be used exactly for that, and that's how `foldl'` works.

Again quoting the wiki,

> foldr is not only the right fold, it is also **most commonly the right
>   fold to use**, in particular when transforming lists (or other
>   foldables) into lists with related elements in the same order.
>   Notably, foldr will be effective for transforming even infinite lists
>   into other infinite lists. For such purposes, it should be your first
>   and most natural choice. For example, note that foldr (:) []==id.

The problem with foldl' is that it reverses the list. If you have a commutative function that is not a problem, so if your list is finite (remember foldl has to travel it all), `foldl'` is usually better. On the other hand, if your function for some reasons does not necessarily need the whole list, or the list might be infinite, go for `foldr`

Comment: While I agree with your eventual solution—namely, use `foldl'`—I think a lot of things in your surrounding explanation aren’t quite right. The problem is not just that `+` is strict in both its arguments, but that `foldr` is *lazy*; the fact that you say `+'` in Clojure must not be strict in both its arguments doesn’t make any sense because Clojure is not a lazy programming language. The reason it is a problem in Haskell is because of the creation of thunks, but this does not happen in Clojure because its `reduce` is essentially Haskell’s `foldl'`; that is, it is strict in its accumulator.

Comment: Furthermore, you write that “`foldl` has to travel the whole list twice before returning a result”, which is not true. `foldl` does have to travel the whole list before returning a result, but it only has to do it once. This is in contrast with `foldr`, which doesn’t have to travel the whole list even once before returning a result if the accumulation function is lazy in its second argument. However, both of these things are immaterial in a case where the accumulation function is strict, since the whole list will have to be traversed, anyway.

Comment: thank you (both). Looks like my mistake was jumping to conclusions, before finishing the whole page, eh. Specifically, implenebting our own versions of foldl and foldr sounded like a good exercise - but, I thought, surely Prelude's versions will be already perfect and not run into overflows... which, I see, is due to (+), and not fold's implementation.

Comment: @AlexisKing That was my understanding, which is probably wrong if you say so. I am happy to make it a wiki answer if you wanna contribute or you can just write your own answer if thats easier

Comment: @alexakarpov It's a decent assumption (that the prelude versions would be good).  I am a bit bewlidered by `foldl` –– I've been using Haskell for over ten years and have never encountered a situation where `foldl` was useful.  It's either `foldr` or `foldl'`.

Comment: @luqui, `foldl` is essentially never useful for lists. OTOH, it's just right for folding a `Set`, `Seq`, etc., "backwards". For example, `foldl (flip (:)) []` will produce a descending list of `Set` elements or convert a sequence to a reversed list. The same applies to `foldr'`: it's worthless for lists but sometimes useful for other structures.

Comment: @dfeuer, oh the `Foldable` one.  I still haven't updated my map of those functions to `Foldable` -- I guess it's been a while now.  But yeah, it seems the problem is that the fold associativity is incompatible with list's associativity; `foldl` would be perfect for `data Tsil a = Lin | Snoc [a] a`.  Cool, I hadn't realized that!

Comment: @AlexisKing `foldl` traverses the list "twice" in the sense that it traverses it once to build the thunk result, and then *that thunk* is "traversed" too, to be evaluated, unfolding the stack, which is then folded back (which could be seen as the *third* "traversal"). that's my theory anyway.

Comment: @WillNess Good point. That does seem like the most reasonable interpretation, though I still wouldn’t personally consider it quite the same as traversing the list twice!