# How to make a tail recursive function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, merge, tail-recursion

I am really confused on how to make a function "Tail recursive".

Here is my function, but I don't know whether it is already tail recursive or not.

I am trying to merge two lists in Haskell.

```
merge2 :: Ord a =>[a]->[a]->[a]
merge2 xs [] = xs
merge2 [] ys = ys
merge2 (x:xs)(y:ys) = if y < x then y: merge2 (x:xs) ys else x :merge2 xs (y:ys)
```

Comment: Related: https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion

Comment: Take particular note of "guarded recursion" in WillemVanOnsem's link. Your `merge2` function isn't tail-recursive, but all its recursion is guarded recursion, which is typically more important in Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

Your function isn't tail-recursive; it's guarded recursive. However, guarded recursion is what you should be using in Haskell if you want to be memory efficient.

For a call to be a tail call, its result must be the result of the entire function. This definition applies to both recursive and non-recursive calls.

For example, in the code

```
f x y z = (x ++ y) ++ z
```

the call `(x ++ y) ++ z` is a tail call because its result is the result of the entire function. The call `x ++ y` is *not* a tail call.

For an example of tail-recursion, consider `foldl`:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl _ acc []     = acc
foldl f acc (x:xs) = foldl f (f acc x) xs
```

The recursive call `foldl f (f acc x) xs` is a tail-recursive call because its result is the result of the entire function. Thus it's a tail call, and it is recursive being a call of `foldl` to itself.

The recursive calls in your code

```
merge2 (x:xs) (y:ys) = if y < x then y : merge2 (x:xs) ys 
                                else x : merge2 xs (y:ys)
```

are not tail-recursive because they do not give the result of the entire function. The result of the call to `merge2` is used as a part of the whole returned value, a new list. The `(:)` constructor, not the recursive call, gives the result of the entire function. And in fact, being lazy, `(:) _ _` returns right away, and the holes `_` are filled only later, if and when needed. That's why guarded recursion is space efficient.

However, tail-recursion doesn't guarantee space efficiency in a lazy language.
With lazy evaluation, Haskell builds up *thunks*, or structures in memory that represent code that is yet to be evaluated. Consider the evaluation of the following code:

```
foldl f 0 (1:2:3:[])
=> foldl f (f 0 1) (2:3:[])
=> foldl f (f (f 0 1) 2) (3:[])
=> foldl f (f (f (f 0 1) 2) 3) []
=> f (f (f 0 1) 2) 3
```

You can think of lazy evaluation as happening "outside-in." When the recursive calls to `foldl` are evaluated, thunks are built-up in the accumulator. So, tail recursion with accumulators is not space efficient in a lazy language because of the delayed evaluation (unless the accumulator is *forced* right away, before the next tail-recursive call is made, thus preventing the thunks build-up and instead presenting the already-calculated value, in the end).

Rather than tail recursion, you should try to use guarded recursion, where the recursive call is hidden inside a lazy data constructor. With lazy evaluation, expressions are evaluated until they are in *weak head normal form* (WHNF). An expression is in WHNF when it is either:

- A lazy data constructor applied to arguments (e.g. `Just (1 + 1)`)
- A partially applied function (e.g. `const 2`)
- A lambda expression (e.g. `\x -> x`)

Consider `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

map (+1) (1:2:3:[])
=> (+1) 1 : map (+1) (2:3:[])
```

The expression `(+1) 1 : map (+1) (2:3:[])` is in WHNF because of the `(:)` data constructor, and therefore evaluation stops at this point. Your `merge2` function also uses guarded recursion, so it too is space-efficient in a lazy language.

TL;DR: In a lazy language, tail-recursion can still take up memory if it builds up thunks in the accumulator, while guarded recursion does not build up thunks.

Helpful links:

- https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion
- https://wiki.haskell.org/Stack_overflow
- https://wiki.haskell.org/Thunk
- https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form
- [Does Haskell have tail-recursive optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042353/8887578)
- [What is Weak Head Normal Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6872898/8887578)