# How can I maximise the efficiency of this function?

Tags: haskell

```hs
encrypt k iv x  = encrypt [] x iv k
    where 
        go _ [] _ _  = []
        go [] x iv k = go [add (add (head x) iv) k] x iv k
        go c x iv k
            | length x == length c = c
            | otherwise            = go (c ++ [add (add (x !! length c) (last c)) k]) x iv k
```

I was wondering whether this function would be considered tail-recursive. By definition, the method we have been assigned to implement is recursive. But, to try and make it more efficient, I tried to make it tail-recursive. Am I wrong in my logic, thinking this is tail-recursive, and that it would be more efficient?

I would also like to know whether the above implementation would be more efficient than the prior implementation below:

```hs
encrypt k iv x = [ go x i iv k | i <- [0..n] ]
    where
        go x 0 iv k  = add (add (x !! 0) iv) k
        go x i iv k  = add (add (x !! i) (encrypt x (i - 1) iv k)) k
        n                 = length x - 1
```

I assumed that since each new element would have to recur back to the first element, this would be highly inefficient. My main goal is to make this function as efficient as I can.

Comment: It is tail-recursive, but [that’s not always good in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization)!

Comment: thank you for the response! i was wondering whether the tail-recursive implementation would benefit efficiency in this case. or, at least, in comparison to my old implementation.

Comment: Using `!!` and `length`, etc. is often not a good idea with regards to efficiency.

Comment: The original isn’t idiomatic either – if you’re going to use the built-in list type (which is a linked list), you should pattern-match one block at a time off the front.

Comment: Concerning your question about the relative efficiency of both versions, you can start by measuring the performance using a library like [tasty-bench](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-bench).

Comment: To add to @WillemVanOnsem's comment, `longlist ++ shortlist` and in particular `longlist ++ [element]` are also generally bad for performance.

Comment: @vkryuu: is it perhaps possible to explain *what* the function is supposed to do, likely this description allows to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am reading this code right, almost certainly both approaches are going to be bad compared to this one:

```
cbcEncrypt k iv [] = []
cbcEncrypt k iv (x:xs) = iv' : cbcEncrypt k iv' xs where
    iv' = add (add x iv) k
```

I am confident of my efficiency evaluation, but I may not have read the code right, so you should read this for yourself and verify that it performs the correct calculation.

This can also be written as a scan.

```
cbcEncrypt k iv0 = tail . scanl (\iv x -> add (add x iv) k) iv0
```

Comment: thank you so much! i ran my test cases and this worked perfectly. i can understand the first implementation, but i am struggling to properly understand how the second one works.

Comment: @vkryuu Explaining the connection between the first implementation and the second is not super hard, but it is definitely *longer* than a comment could reasonably contain. If you continue to have trouble connecting them after a bit more work, I encourage you to open another question describing your thoughts and where you're stuck/confused!

Comment: i did some further reading and eventually understood. thank you again for the help!