# Create list of strings from list of doubles, non Scientific notation

Tags: haskell, floating-point

```
listOfLongDeci = [showFFloat Nothing (1/a) | a<-[2..1000], length (show (1/a)) > 7]

listOfLongDeci2 = [show (1/a) | a<-[2..1000], length (show (1/a)) > 7]

listOfLongDeci3 = [(1/a) | a<-[2..1000], length (show (1/a)) > 7]
```

- the 1st gives a list of ShowS, how can I make a string from showS?
- the 2nd gives a list of scientific notation
- the 3rd only gives list
  of doubles

How can I use any of these to create a list of strings with non scientific notation? ([Euler 26](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26))

Comment: Maybe you want `Text.Printf.printf`.

Comment: `showFFloat Nothing (1/a) ""` gives you a `String`.

Comment: thx, @DanielFischer, i thought i tried that, but I must have messed up

Comment: Didn't see the Project Euler reference at first. Floating point won't help you with that problem. It's easiest done in pure integer arithmetic (do a couple like `1/7`, `1/13`, `1/81` by hand to see what's going on).

Comment: I know it might not be the best solution, but I allways want to try my way first, and then looking into other solutions.

Comment: It's not only not the best solution, it won't work. For example, `1/71` has a recurring cycle `01408450704225352112676056338028169` of length 35. A `Double` gives you about 16 significant (decimal) digits of precision, that's not enough. The closest value to `1/71` representable as a `Double` is `0.01408450704225352144438598855913369334302842617034912109375`. There's simply no way to obtain the cycle or its length from that except by going back to the integer 71 and starting from there.

Comment: @DanielFischer another nag about submitting a comment as an answer :-) You manage to swoop in and give answers to all these things so succinctly, and then they never get officially answered because you've already taken care of it.

Comment: @sclv Nagging successful (this time, at least), got an official answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691986/create-list-of-strings-from-list-of-doubles-non-scientific-notation?noredirect=1#comment24085238_16691986):

> the 1st gives a list of `ShowS`, how can I make a `String` from `ShowS`?

Since `ShowS` is a type synonym for `String -> String`, you obtain a `String` by applying the function to a `String`. Since the `showXFloat` functions produce a function that prepends some `String` to the final `String` argument (basically a difference list; many `show`-related functions produce such - `shows`, `showChar`, `showString`, to name a few - [for reasons of efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/1011995)), the natural choice for the final argument is the empty `String`, so

```
listOfLongDeci = [showFFloat Nothing (1/a) "" | a<-[2..1000], length (show (1/a)) > 7]
```

produces a list of `String`s, correctly rounded approximations to the decimal representation of the numbers `1/a` in non scientific notation.

> how can I use any of these to create a list of strings with non scientific notation? (euler 26)

The first part has been answered, but these representations won't help you solve [Problem 26](http://projecteuler.net/problem=26) of Project Euler,

> Find the value of `d < 1000` for which `1/d` contains the longest recurring cycle in its decimal fraction part.

A `Double` has 53 bits of precision (52 explicit bits for the significand plus one hidden bit for normalized numbers, no hidden bit, thus 52 or fewer bits of precision for subnormal numbers), and the number `1/d` cannot be exactly represented as a `Double` unless `d` is a power of 2. The 53 bits of precision give you roughly

```
Prelude> 53 * log 2 / log 10
15.954589770191001
```

significant decimal digits of precision, so from the first nonzero digit on, you have 15 or 16 digits that you can expect to be correct for the exact [terminating or recurring] decimal expansion of the fraction `1/d`, beyond that, the expansions differ.

For example, `1/71` has a recurring cycle `01408450704225352112676056338028169` of length 35 (by far not the longest in the range to be considered). The closest representable `Double` to `1/71` is

```
0.01408450704225352144438598855913369334302842617034912109375 = 8119165525400331 / (2^59)
```

of which the first 17 significant digits are correct (and `0.014084507042253521` is also what `showFFloat Nothing (1/71) ""` gives you).

To find the longest recurring cycle in the decimal expansion of `1/d`, you can use an exact (or sufficiently accurate finite) string representation of the `Rational` number `1 % d`, or, better, use pure integer arithmetic (compute the decimal expansion using long division) without involving a `Rational`.