# Reversing a list, evaluation order

Tags: haskell

[image]

I am reading page 69 of Haskell School of Expression and I am not sure that I got the evalution of `rev [1:2:3:4]` right.

Hudak does not explain the evalution(rewriting) order in detail in his book for `reverse`.

Could someone please either confirm that my guess (shown in the attached picture) is correct or if not correct then point out what I got wrong. I believe that it is correct but I am  not 100% sure, this is the reason for asking.

So the question is:

when I evaluate one step of `reverse` then aftes the evaluation (i.e. rewriting) the result should be surrounded by parenthesis, right?

If I understand correctly, these unlucky appearance of parentheseses is the reason for the poor (read quadratic) time complexity of `reverse`. In this  example 6 steps are spent in total on list appending in order to reverse a 4 element list.

Comment: It looks like just a "typo", but your definition for `rev` is wrong, you should be using `++` not `:` on the right hand side of the `(x:xs)` case.

Comment: It looks like you have the evaluation order correct, but for some explanations of why this is slow, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874719/why-haskell-list-is-more-efficient-if-its-left-associate/23874845#23874845) question.

Comment: Thanks bheklir, indeed that is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, nested, left-associative calls to append (in Haskell, goes by the names `(++)` and `(<>)`) generates poor performance of singly-linked lists.

There are several solutions to this problem, since it's been known about for 30 or 40 years, at least.  I believe the library version of `reverse` uses an accumulator to achieve linear complexity rather than quadratic, but it's still not something you want to call frequently on lists.

Comment: @DanielWagner Doh! You're right, I must have read the output wrong because I typed it in to check.  But the `foldl' (flip (:)) []` implementation does actually reverse the list.