# fail to use foldl to reverse a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, fold

I know how to use recursion to reverse a list, but I am trying to use foldl to make it more efficient. My code is as follow:

```
reverse list = foldl (++) [] (map (\x -> [x]) list)
```

When running it in GHCi, it returns the same list as input. What goes wrong? I also try to finish it by foldr but it does not show any change.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847192/reverse-a-list-in-haskell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a list in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847192/reverse-a-list-in-haskell)

Comment: @icc97 though a correct `foldl` solution is given in that question, the question itself not really about that, so I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.

Comment: @leftaroundabout OP wants to use `foldl` to reverse a list the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26847373/327074) to the duplicate question gives: `reverseList = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []`

Comment: As I was saying, the solution is sure there. Just, a _question duplicate_ should actually be asking the same question, and it's not really adressed over there why `foldl` without `flip` gives the the result in the wrong order.

Comment: your definition gives `reverse [1,2,3] = (([] ++ [1]) ++ [2]) ++ [3]`. the same definition with `foldr` would produce `reverse [1,2,3] = [1] ++ reverse [2,3]`.

Answer (score 3):

`foldl` passes the accumulator as the first argument to the function. `++` concatenates the first argument to the second, but, to reverse a list, you need to concatenate the second to the first. You can do this using `flip (++)`:

```
Prelude> let reverse list = foldl (flip (++)) [] (map (\x -> [x]) list)
Prelude> reverse [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: "concatenates ... to" is non-directional; confusing. "before" would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of first converting all elements of the list to singleton lists (which is expensive as well), you can use the cons `(:)` function:

```
reverse :: Foldable t => t a  -> [a]
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

So here we use `flip (:) :: [a] -> a -> [a]` as fold function. It takes a tail `[a]` and a head `a`, and constructs a list with the head as first element and the tail as last element.

So what happens is:

```
   foldl (flip (:)) [] [1,4,2,5]
-> foldl (flip (:)) (1:[]) [4,2,5]
-> foldl (flip (:)) (4:1:[]) [2,5]
-> foldl (flip (:)) (2:4:1:[]) [5]
-> foldl (flip (:)) (5:2:4:1:[]) []
-> (5:2:4:1:[])
-> [5,2,4,1]
```

Comment: im always struggling with the difference foldl vs foldr, why use foldl here? would you mind a quick explanation? thanks!

Comment: @DanielSanchez: `foldr` starts a the right end of the list (or more general the foldable). So if the list is `[a,b,c,d]`, it will calculate `f a (f b (f c (f d z)))`. Whereas `foldl` will calculate `f (f (f (f z a) b) c) d`. With `z` the initial element`.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks for your advice.