# Does haskell let me mix types of lists?

Tags: haskell

So I was told that list have 2 forms:

1. `(a:as)`, where `a` is the head and `as` is the tail
2. `[a]`, where `a` is the list

My question here is that if the function I'm working on `inverte :: [a]->[a]`

Can I use the type `(a:as)` when I'm defining the function;

For example

```
inverte::[a]->[a]
inverte [] =[]
inverte (a:as) = (as:a)
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No lists have two forms `(a:[a])` and `[]`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your aim is. It might be clearer to give some example inputs/outputs of the function(s) you are trying to write.

Comment: im recreating the function reverse

Comment: 1 thing that i dint understand, so i did  inverte::[a]->[a] inverte [] =[] inverte (a:as) = inverte(as) ++ [a], and it works but the function didint read a ? when its suposed to only read [a] , isnt the function mixing types?

Comment: (a:as) is not a type. Using the same letter for type variable and values of a given type can be confusing. When you say `inverte::[a]->[a]`, `a` is a type, you say that `inverte` takes a list of elements of any type `a` and returns a list of elements of the same given type `a`. For the next two sentences you are saying how the functions works on empty lists `[]` and on lists of at least one element `(a:as)`. In this case, `a` is an _element of type_ `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the compiler will tell you that this is not possible!

You are mixing up two different "views" of list. To make clear what I speak of let us define a different implementation of list.

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | EmptyList

mylist :: List Char
mylist = Cons 'a' (Cons 'h' (Cons 'a' (Cons '!' EmptyList)))

oldlist :: [Char]
oldlist = 'a' : ('h' : ('a' : ('!' : [])))
-- or
oldlist = ['a','h','a','!']
-- alternatively you could write this as
oldlist = "aha!"
-- because `String` is just a list of `Char`.
```

On the left hand side you write what new data type you define and on the right hand side there are all the operators you provide to construct such a type or to pattern match in a function definition.

Now back to the haskell built in list type - and to make things a bit more obvious I will call the "value level"-variables `x`, and the type-variables `a`

- `(x:xs)` and `[]` are the two pattern to match on a list, here

  - `(x:xs)` corresponds to `Cons x xs`, and
  - `[]` to `Emptylist`
- `List a` is the type of those expressions and corresponds to `[a]`.

---

Now when you try to build your function `inverte` we have to take a closer look at `(x:xs)` - and inspect the types of the components of your pattern match as well as the right hand side in that line.

```
x   :: a
xs  :: [a]
(:) :: b -> [b] -> [b] -- this is how you write an operator as a function
                       -- ps: we can name the type variables however we want ;-)
```

On the right hand side you write `(xs:x)` or `(:) xs x`
- I hope you can see that this is a problem...

### But how to solve this ??

with this `(:)` operator - sadly you cannot - but fortunately enough there is another operator that will do the trick!

### And how do we find it??

I can give you hints - the operator you look for has type signature -

```
 ?? :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

another thing we need is to make `x` into a list - this is so easy that I will spoil the fun: just take `[x]`

To find your operator you might find [hoogle](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) a great help

Comment: 1 thing that i dint understand, so i did  inverte::[a]->[a] inverte [] =[] inverte (a:as) = inverte(as) ++ [a], and it works but the function didint read a ? when its suposed to only read [a] , isnt the function mixing types?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "read [a]" - if you mean the case of `inverte [x] = [x]` it is a special case because `[x]` is the same as `(x:[])`.

Comment: in inverte(a:as) = inverte(as) ++[a]  , he reads (a:as) when the type is [a]->[a]

Comment: i think you have a bit of misunderstanding what function definition in haskell is - so I would recommend reading a chapter or more of http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters - you are mixing two different levels as I said - type level and value level - `[a]` is type level - whereas `(x:xs)` is value level. there is no mixing of types!

Answer (score 0):

That will fail. I'm going to rewrite your last line using different variable names for clarity:

```
inverte (x:xs) = (xs:x)
```

The variable `x` is of type `a`, but the variable `xs` is of type `[a]` (i.e. a list of `a`. The `:` operator requires its first argument to be an element and its second to be a list of the same type. So swapping them over won't work.

A legal (but slow) way is to say `xs ++ [x]`. You might also want to look at [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847192/reverse-a-list-in-haskell).