# Reverse own list a more optimal way

Tags: haskell

Tried to mimic the `reverse` function to the ADT `List` below,

```
 data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show)                                                                   

 reverseList = convert . reverse'                                                                                      
     where                                                                                                             
         reverse' Nil = []                                                                                             
         reverse' (Cons x list) = reverse' list ++ [x]                                                                 

         convert [] = Nil                                                                                              
         convert (x:xs) = Cons x (convert xs)
```

The `reverseList` is composed of `convert` and `reverse'`, how to achieve it optimally for instance without the aid of the built-in list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view, the most basic O(N) solution is to use recursion and an accumulator:

```
revlist :: List a -> List a
revlist xs = go xs Nil
   where
   go ::  List a -> List a -> List a
   go Nil         zs = zs
   go (Cons y ys) zs = go ys (Cons y zs)
```

This exploits `go`, a tail-recursive function which essentially uses the two lists as stacks, repeatedly popping elements form the first stack and pushing them to the second stack. Once the first stack is empty, the second stack contains the reversed list.

Comment: This is exactly how [reverse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#reverse) in `Data.List` does!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26847373/7096763) to a similar question, you can let the compiler derive a `Traversable` instance to your `List` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
--You need the Functor and Foldable instances
```

Then, `reverse'` becomes simply:

```
reverse' = foldl (flip Cons) Nil
```

which is O(N) time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is translate all the list functions you're using to ones on your `List` type. Here this means `++` - let's define this for your version, and call it say `listConcat` (feel free to come up with your own name):

```
listConcat :: List a -> List a -> List a
listConcat Nil as = as
listConcat (Cons a as) bs = Cons a (listConcat as bs)
```

And then you can just translate the definition of `reverseList` that you already have:

```
reverseList :: List a -> List a
reverseList Nil = Nil
reverseList (Cons a as) = listConcat (reverseList as) (Cons a Nil)
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that this has still quadratic complexity while it could be O(N), e.g. using an accumulator-based recursive function. OP asks for "optimality", and I am unsure about what they actually want.

Comment: Good point @chi, I interpreted the OP as just asking to write the function pure in terms of the `List` type without involving the built-in list type, and hadn't even considered complexity or how to reduce it. But I will happily admit, having thought about it, that this is `O(n^2)` and therefore very bad.

Answer (score 1):

You may perhaps do it in an applicative style efficiently. It should be O(n)

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving Show

conc :: List a -> List a -> List a
conc Nil xs = xs
conc (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x $ conc xs ys

revlist :: List a -> List a
revlist xs = go xs Nil                                  -- invoke go xs function by Nil
             where
             go ::  List a -> (List a -> List a)
             go Nil         = conc Nil                  -- such as ([]++)
             go (Cons x xs) = go xs . conc (Cons x Nil) -- such as go xs . ([x]++)

λ> revlist (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)))
Cons 3 (Cons 2 (Cons 1 Nil))
```

We are nesting the concatenation operations (`conc`) to the right. This is basically difference lists.

Comment: This is O(N), but I find it a bit more complex than needed. We can replace `conc Nil` with `id`. Further, `conc (Cons x Nil)` can be written as `Cons x`. At that point, `conc` is no longer needed.

Comment: @chi I shouldn't say that i have thought your points and left them so deliberately since i haven't... You are right, however i think, still it's fine this way since along with the comments in the code, they might be helpful for those who might get curious to understand what's going on.