# Explicit Purely-Functional Data-Structure For Difference Lists

Tags: haskell, data-structures, purely-functional, difference-lists

In Haskell, [*difference lists*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list), in the sense of

> [a] representation of a list with an efficient concatenation operation

seem to be [implemented in terms of function composition](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/john-hughes/lists.pdf).

Functions and (dynamic) function compositions, though, must also be represented somehow in the computer's memory using data structures, which raises the question of how [dlists](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/data-structures.html) could be implemented in Haskell *without* using function compositions, but, rather, through some basic purely-functional node-based data structures. How could this be done with the same performance guarantees as those of function composition?

Comment: I'd expect this would be impossible. To have a fast append at the front and at the end you need two pointers, roughly. in dlists, the pointer to the closure provides for the front, and the lambda-abstracted variable roughly provides the pointer to the end. If you only use node-based stuff, you have trees, at best, and you can't achieve the same performance, I guess. However, keep in mind that 2-3 finger trees have an impressively good amortized performance (see `Data.Sequence`).

Comment: @chi Thanks for the pointer of 2-3 finger trees! Will read up on them.

Comment: You actually can do this with a data structure: `data DList a = Empty | Single a | Append (DList a) (DList a)` will give the same asymoptotics for `cons`, `snoc`, `append`, and `toList`. I don't have time to write up a full answer now, though, and I'm sure you could find a better representation if you desire.

Comment: @carl Thanks, that sounds correct. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Carl I don't think that's true. `toList`-ing a left-associative sequence of `Append`s will be just as slow as evaluating a left-associative sequence of `(++)`s.

Comment: You can write an O(m + n) `toList` for that. You just need to never use `(++) `, which means traversing back-to-front with an accumulator.

Comment: @Carl ...and then you've written `DList` :)

Comment: You do need to work with CPS representation of the result to recover laziness in `toList`, though. So.. There is that.

Comment: Well, no. You can write a non-lazy `toList` without ever touching a CPS representation. You only need CPS to recover laziness.

Comment: @Carl I just meant "right to left with an accumulator" is exactly the evaluation strategy which `DList` implements

Comment: In the presence of laziness, `DList` uses a left-to-right evaluation strategy that uses an implicit continuation for the rest of the output instead of an accumulator.

Comment: @TheOrgazoid Well, no, Carl's proposed tree-like `data DList a` isn't yet the real `DList`, because it hasn't yet had the deforestation optimization applied. (Which is a pretty good way to understand how `DList` came to be the way it is, actually: you start with Carl's implementation, then apply some optimizations.)

Comment: @DanielWagner I've added a simple solution with a similar, though different type than Carl's. the "deforestation" isn't done in full, but rather partially, minimally, only as much as needed to ensure the O(1) amortized access, whatever the sequence of appends a user performed to create the dlist thing.

Comment: find "defunctionalized difference list" [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/difference-lists-in-functional-programming) and elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

`(++)`'s notoriously bad asymptotics come about when you use it in a left-associative manner - that is, when `(++)`'s left argument is the result of another call to `(++)`. Right-associative expressions run efficiently, though.

To put it more concretely: evaluating a left-nested append of `m` lists like

```
((ws ++ xs) ++ ys) ++ zs  -- m = 3 in this example
```

to WHNF requires you to force `m` thunks, because `(++)` is strict in its left argument.

```
case (
    case (
        case ws of { [] -> xs ; (w:ws) -> w:(ws ++ xs) }
    ) of { [] -> ys ; (x:xs) -> x:(xs ++ ys) }
) of { [] -> zs ; (y:ys) -> y:(ys ++ zs) }
```

In general, to fully evaluate `n` elements of such a list, this'll require forcing that stack of `m` thunks `n` times, for O(m*n) complexity. When the entire list is built from appends of singleton lists (ie `(([w] ++ [x]) ++ [y]) ++ [z]`), `m = n` so the cost is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Evaluating a right-nested append like

```
ws ++ (xs ++ (ys ++ zs))
```

to WHNF is much easier (O(1)):

```
case ws of
    [] -> xs ++ (ys ++ zs)
    (w:ws) -> w:(ws ++ (xs ++ (ys ++ zs)))
```

Evaluating `n` elements just requires evaluating `n` thunks, which is about as good as you can expect to do.

---

Difference lists work by paying a small (O(m)) up-front cost to automatically *re-associate calls to `(++)`*.

```
newtype DList a = DList ([a] -> [a])
fromList xs = DList (xs ++)
toList (DList f) = f []

instance Monoid (DList a) where
    mempty = fromList []
    DList f `mappend` DList g = DList (f . g)
```

Now a left-nested expression,

```
toList (((fromList ws <> fromList xs) <> fromList ys) <> fromList zs)
```

gets evaluated in a right-associative manner:

```
((((ws ++) . (xs ++)) . (ys ++)) . (zs ++)) []

-- expand innermost (.)
(((\l0 -> ws ++ (xs ++ l0)) . (ys ++)) . (zs ++)) []

-- expand innermost (.)
((\l1 -> (\l0 -> ws ++ (xs ++ l0)) (ys ++ l1)) . (zs ++)) []
-- beta reduce
((\l1 -> ws ++ (xs ++ (ys ++ l1))) . (zs ++)) []

-- expand innermost (.)
(\l2 -> (\l1 -> ws ++ (xs ++ (ys ++ l1))) (zs ++ l2)) []
-- beta reduce
(\l2 -> ws ++ (xs ++ (ys ++ (zs ++ l2)))) []
-- beta reduce
ws ++ (xs ++ (ys ++ (zs ++ [])))
```

You perform O(m) steps to evaluate the composed function, then O(n) steps to evaluate the resulting expression, for a total complexity of O(m+n), which is asymptotically better than O(m*n). When the list is made up entirely of appends of singleton lists, `m = n` and you get O(2n) ~ O(n), which is asymptotically better than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

This trick works for any `Monoid`.

```
newtype RMonoid m = RMonoid (m -> m)  -- "right-associative monoid"
toRM m = RMonoid (m <>)
fromRM (RMonoid f) = f mempty
instance Monoid m => Monoid (RMonoid m):
    mempty = toRM mempty
    RMonoid f `mappend` RMonoid g = RMonoid (f . g)
```

See also, for example, [the Codensity monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html), which applies this idea to monadic expressions built using `(>>=)` (rather than monoidal expressions built using `(<>)`).

---

I hope I have convinced you that `(++)` only causes a problem when used in a left-associative fashion. Now, you can easily write a list-like data structure for which append is strict in its *right* argument, and left-associative appends are therefore not a problem.

```
data Snoc a = Nil | Snoc (Snoc a) a

xs +++ Nil = xs
xs +++ (Snoc ys y) = Snoc (xs +++ ys) y
```

We recover O(1) WHNF of left-nested appends,

```
((ws +++ xs) +++ ys) +++ zs

case zs of
    Nil -> (ws +++ xs) +++ ys
    Snoc zs z -> Snoc ((ws +++ xs) +++ ys) +++ zs) z
```

but at the expense of slow right-nested appends.

```
ws +++ (xs +++ (ys +++ zs))

case (
    case (
        case zs of { Nil -> ys ; (Snoc zs z) -> Snoc (ys +++ zs) z }
    ) of { Nil -> xs ; (Snoc ys y) -> Snoc (xs +++ ys) y }
) of { Nil -> ws ; (Snoc xs x) -> Snoc (ws +++ xs) y }
```

Then, of course, you end up writing a new type of difference list which reassociates appends to the left!

```
newtype LMonoid m = LMonoid (m -> m)  -- "left-associative monoid"
toLM m = LMonoid (<> m)
fromLM (LMonoid f) = f mempty
instance Monoid m => Monoid (LMonoid m):
    mempty = toLM mempty
    LMonoid f `mappend` LMonoid g = LMonoid (g . f)
```

Comment: Does this actually answer the question somewhere?

Comment: @DanielWagner If you interpret the question as "Can I write a list-shaped datatype with efficient _left-nested_ concatenation?" then yes - that's `Snoc`. Granted, that's a rather generous interpretation of the question. So, um, no, not really. :)

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879260/why-are-difference-lists-more-efficient-than-regular-concatenation/13879693#13879693) the trick is the rearrangement of `(.)` tree into the `($)` list on access.

We can emulate this  with

```
data Dlist a = List [a]  
             | Append (Dlist a) (Dlist a)
```

which will juggle the `Append` nodes, rotating the tree to the right, to push the leftmost node up so it becomes the uppermost-left, on the first access, after which the next `tail`<sup>(**)</sup> operation becomes *O(1)* <sup>(*)</sup> :

```
let x = (List [1..10] `Append` List [11..20]) `Append` List [21..30]
```

and `tail x`<sup>(**)</sup> is to produce

```
List [2..10] `Append` (List [11..20] `Append` List [21..30])
```

`tail`<sup>(**)</sup> should be trivial to implement. Of course if will only pattern match the leftmost `List` node's list (with `(x:xs)`) when that node is finally discovered, and won't touch contents of anything else inside the `Append` nodes as they are juggled. Laziness is thus naturally preserved.

---

<sup>(**)</sup> *2020 edit*: what this actually means is to have one `uncons :: Dlist a -> (a, Dlist a)` operation producing the head and the new, rotated tail, simultaneously, so that `uncons` on the *new* tail is *O(1)*.<sup>(*)</sup>

---

<sup>(*)</sup> *edit:* *O(1)* in case the leftmost `List` node's list isn't empty. Overall, taking into account the possible nested-on-the-left `Append` nodes that will have to be rearranged as *they* come to the fore after the first leftmost `List` node is exhausted, the access to all *n* elements of the result will be *O(n+m)*, where *m* is the number of empty lists.

---

*update:* A historical note: this is actually quite similar (if not exactly the same) as the efficient tree-fringe enumeration problem, dealt with in 1977 by John McCarthy, whose [`gopher`](http://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html) function did exactly the same kind of nodes re-arrangement (tree rotations to the right) as the proposed here `tail`<sup>(**)</sup> would.

Comment: Many thanks - this looks simple (in the positive sense) and good.

Comment: this just is doing exactly what is happening implicitly with the (.)-based dlists. Nothing more, nothing less. :)

Comment: I expect you're right - still studying this language, though. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: do check out the linked answer, it's canonical. (and maybe, *its* linked questions).

Comment: Yes, your type is a bit simpler to work with, but I think Carl's mimics the `DList` representation a bit more closely. I've added a note to my answer mentioning the deconstruction issue.

Comment: FWIW, even the DList on Hackage doesn't claim `tail` is O(1).

Comment: @DanielWagner "*after which* it becomes..." so, it is amortized, obviously.

Comment: @dfeuer the question is the efficiency and laziness of `fromList` + repeated appends in whatever order. which is trivially clear with this representation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I like this representation better than the one I suggested. :)

Comment: and `last` can be implemented so that it successfully returns `0` for `Append (Append (List [1]) (List [2..])) (List [0])`. see also [this](http://comonad.com/reader/2015/free-monoids-in-haskell/).

Comment: later note: of course `head` and `tail` should be done together, as `unCons :: Dlist a -> Maybe (a, Dlist a)`, to get the rearranged tail at the same time as the head.

Answer (score 3):

Carl hit it in his comment. We can write

```
data TList a = Nil | Single a | Node !(TList a) (TList a)

singleton :: a -> TList a
singleton = Single

instance Monoid (TList a) where
  mempty = Nil
  mappend = Node
```

We could get `toList` by just deriving `Foldable`, but let's write it out instead to see just what's going on.

```
instance Foldable TList where
  foldMap _ Nil = mempty
  foldMap f (Single a) = f a
  foldMap f (Node t u) = foldMap f t <> foldMap f u

  toList as0 = go as0 [] where
    go Nil k = k
    go (Single a) k = a : k
    go (Node l r) k = go l (go r k)
```

`toList` is O(n), where n is the total number of internal nodes (i.e., the total number of `mappend` operations used to form the `TList`). This should be pretty clear: each `Node` is inspected exactly once. `mempty`, `mappend`, and `singleton` are each obviously O(1).

This is exactly the same as for a `DList`:

```
newtype DList a = DList ([a] -> [a])
singletonD :: a -> DList a
singletonD a = DList (a:)
instance Monoid (DList a) where
  mempty = DList id
  mappend (DList f) (DList g) = DList (f . g)
instance Foldable DList where
  foldr c n xs = foldr c n (toList xs)
  toList (DList f) = f []
```

Why, operationally, is this the same? Because, as you indicate in your question, the functions are represented in memory as trees. And they're represented as trees that look a lot like `TList`s! `singletonD x` produces a closure containing a (boring) `(:)` and an exciting `x`. When applied, it does O(1) work. `mempty` just produces the `id` function, which when applied does O(1) work. `mappend as bs` produces a closure that, when applied, does O(1) work of its own, plus O(length as + length bs) work in its children.

The *shapes* of the trees produced for `TList` and `DList` are actually the same. You should be able to convince yourself that they also have identical asymptotic performance when used incrementally: in each case, the program has to walk down the left spine of the tree to get to the first list element.

---

Both `DList` and `TList` are equally okay when built up and then used only once. They're equally lousy when built once and converted to lists multiple times.

As Will Ness showed with a similar type, the explicit tree representation is better if you want to add support for *deconstructing* the representation, as you can actually get your hands on the structure. `TList` can support a reasonably efficient `uncons` operation (that improves the structure as it works). To get efficient `unsnoc` as well, you'll need to use a fancier representation (a catenable deque). This implementation also has potentially wretched cache performance. You can switch to a cache-oblivious data structure, but it is practically guaranteed to be complicated.

Comment: Many thanks - the relation to `Foldable` is especially interesting.

Comment: [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237695/why-does-haskell-use-mergesort-instead-of-quicksort/54067493?noredirect=1#comment95026495_54067493), there's already something very similar, in [Data.Edison.Seq.JoinList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EdisonCore-1.3.2.1/docs/Data-Edison-Seq-JoinList.html#t:Seq) (FYI).