# Split a list into non-empty sub-lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to split the given list into non-empty sub-lists each of which
is either in strictly ascending order, in strictly descending order, or contains all equal elements.  For example, [5,6,7,2,1,1,1] should become [[5,6,7],[2,1],[1,1]].

Here is what I have done so far:

```
splitSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]] 
splitSort ns = foldr k [] ns
  where
    k a []  = [[a]]
    k a ns'@(y:ys) | a <= head y = (a:y):ys
                   | otherwise = [a]:ns'
```

I think I am quite close but when I use it it outputs [[5,6,7],[2],[1,1,1]] instead of [[5,6,7],[2,1],[1,1]].

Comment: @jberryman Uh, isn't that function `\ _ _ -> True`? I can't understand your hint. At the moment, I'm unsure if this can be easily achieved with `foldr`. I'd switch to explicit recursion and use some accumulator argument instead. (Perhaps there's a simpler way?)

Comment: @chi oh you're right, without thinking I interpreted "strictly increasing" to mean a sequence that either ascends or descends by at most one. Obviously this is not what strictly increasing usually means, but I'm not convinced it's not what op wants. Otherwise the problem statement is ambiguous e.g. `map return` is a valid solution. Similarly both examples op gives are valid solutions

Comment: I don’t understand what you want the function to do.  You say one thing, and the example shows something else.

Comment: What should `[1,1,2]` give? Or `[2,1,1,2]`? Is your priority to favor earlier sequences or something more elaborate?

Comment: An observation: the output `[[5,6,7],[2],[1,1,1]]` meets the spec "all sublists non-empty, all sublists either strictly increasing, strictly decreasing, or all-equal".

Comment: @DanielWagner ... and that spec is easily satisfied by `map pure` :) I guess the intent is to make the first list as long as possible, then the second one as long as possible, and so on.

Comment: Presumably a fourth requirement is that it should be "eager", in the sense that the breaks should occur as late as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a kinda ugly solution, with three `reverse` in one line of code :).

```
addElement :: Ord a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
addElement a []  = [[a]]
addElement a (x:xss) = case x of
  (x1:x2:xs) 
    | any (check a x1 x2) [(==),(<),(>)] -> (a:x1:x2:xs):xss
    | otherwise -> [a]:(x:xss)
  _  -> (a:x):xss
  where 
    check x1 x2 x3 op = (x1 `op` x2) && (x2 `op` x3) 

splitSort xs = reverse $ map reverse $ foldr addElement [] (reverse xs)
```

You can possibly get rid of all the reversing if you modify `addElement` a bit.

EDIT:
Here is a less reversing version (even works for infinite lists):

```
splitSort2 []         = []
splitSort2 [x]        = [[x]]
splitSort2 (x:y:xys)  = (x:y:map snd here):splitSort2 (map snd later)
  where 
    (here,later) = span ((==c) . uncurry compare) (zip (y:xys) xys)
    c            = compare x y
```

EDIT 2:
Finally, here is a solution based on a single decorating/undecorating, that avoids comparing any two values more than once and is probably a lot more efficient.

```
splitSort xs = go (decorate xs) where
  decorate :: Ord a => [a] -> [(Ordering,a)]
  decorate xs = zipWith (\x y -> (compare x y,y)) (undefined:xs) xs

  go :: [(Ordering,a)] -> [[a]]
  go ((_,x):(c,y):xys)  = let (here, later) = span ((==c) . fst) xys in 
                              (x : y : map snd here) : go later
  go xs = map (return . snd) xs -- Deal with both base cases
```

Comment: I've posted an answer with a bit simpler code which does what your last code is doing, I think. It's an unfold.

Comment: Clever! Simpler is debatable :). Not quite equivalent since this one is more lazy (e.g. `take 10 $ head $ splitSort [1..]` terminates).

Comment: I wrote "simpler-looking" there, at first, but I guess I edited it to *simplify* it. ;) hmm. Good point about laziness. `length` is usually a no-no, and I played with fusing it into `splitAt` to make it count over the first group's spine instead of the numbers, essentially in unary, but it made the code much less "simpler"-looking so I decided against the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The initial try turned out to be lengthy probably inefficient but i will keep it striked for the sake of integrity with the comments. You best just skip to the end for the answer.

<s>Nice question... but turns out to be a little hard candy. My approach is in segments, those of each i will explain;</s>

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

splitSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
splitSort (x:xs) = (:) <$> (x :) . head <*> tail $ interim
                   where
                   pattern = zipWith compare <$> init <*> tail
                   tuples  = zipWith (,) <$> tail <*> pattern
                   groups  = groupBy (\p c -> snd p == snd c) . tuples $ (x:xs)
                   interim = groups >>= return . map fst

*Main> splitSort [5,6,7,2,1,1,1]
[[5,6,7],[2,1],[1,1]]
```

- The `pattern` function (`zipWith compare <$> init <*> tail`) is of type `Ord a => [a] -> [Ordering]` when fed with `[5,6,7,2,1,1,1]` compares the `init` of it by the `tail` of it by `zipWith`. So the result would be `[LT,LT,GT,GT,EQ,EQ]`. This is the pattern we need.
- The `tuples` function will take the `tail` of our list and will tuple up it's elements with the corresponding elements from the result of `pattern`. So we will end up with something like `[(6,LT),(7,LT),(2,GT),(1,GT),(1,EQ),(1,EQ)]`.
- The `groups` function utilizes [`Data.List.groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/groupBy-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-List-GroupBy.html) over the second items of the tuples and generates the required sublists such as `[[(6,LT),(7,LT)],[(2,GT),(1,GT)],[(1,EQ),(1,EQ)]]`
- Interim is where we monadically get rid of the `Ordering` type values and tuples. The result of interim is `[[6,7],[2,1],[1,1]]`.
- Finally at the main function body `(:) <$> (x :) . head <*> tail $ interim` appends the first item of our list (`x`) to the sublist at `head` (it has to be there whatever the case) and gloriously present the solution.

**Edit:** So investigating the `[0,1,0,1]` resulting `[[0,1],[0],[1]]` problem that @Jonas Duregård discovered, we can conclude that in the result there shall be no sub lists with a length of 1 except for the last one when singled out. I mean for an input like `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0]` the above code produces `[[0,1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0]]` while it should `[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0]]`. So I believe adding a `squeeze` function at the very last stage should correct the logic.

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

splitSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
splitSort []     = []
splitSort [x]    = [[x]]
splitSort (x:xs) = squeeze $ (:) <$> (x :) . head <*> tail $ interim
                   where
                   pattern = zipWith compare <$> init <*> tail
                   tuples  = zipWith (,) <$> tail <*> pattern
                   groups  = groupBy (\p c -> snd p == snd c) $ tuples (x:xs)
                   interim = groups >>= return . map fst

                   squeeze []           = []
                   squeeze [y]          = [y]
                   squeeze ([n]:[m]:ys) = [n,m] : squeeze ys
                   squeeze ([n]:(m1:m2:ms):ys) | compare n m1 == compare m1 m2 = (n:m1:m2:ms) : squeeze ys
                                               | otherwise                     = [n] : (m1:m2:ms) : squeeze ys
                   squeeze (y:ys)       = y : squeeze s

*Main> splitSort [0,1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0]]
*Main> splitSort [5,6,7,2,1,1,1]
[[5,6,7],[2,1],[1,1]]
*Main> splitSort [0,0,1,0,-1]
[[0,0],[1,0,-1]]
```

Yes; as you will also agree the code has turned out to be a little too lengthy and possibly not so efficient.

**The Answer:** I have to trust the back of my head when it keeps telling me i am not on the right track. Sometimes, like in this case, the problem reduces down to a single `if then else` instruction, much simpler than i had initially anticipated.

```
runner :: Ord a => Maybe Ordering -> [a] -> [[a]]
runner _       []  = []
runner _       [p] = [[p]]
runner mo (p:q:rs) = let mo'    = Just (compare p q)
                         (s:ss) = runner mo' (q:rs)
                     in if mo == mo' || mo == Nothing then (p:s):ss
                                                      else [p] : runner Nothing (q:rs)
splitSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
splitSort = runner Nothing
```

My test cases

```
*Main> splitSort [0,1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0]]
*Main> splitSort [5,6,7,2,1,1,1]
[[5,6,7],[2,1],[1,1]]
*Main> splitSort [0,0,1,0,-1]
[[0,0],[1,0,-1]]
*Main> splitSort [1,2,3,5,2,0,0,0,-1,-1,0]
[[1,2,3,5],[2,0],[0,0],[-1,-1],[0]]
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It's missing cases (crashes for ´[]´ and ´[0]´). Also for inputs like `[0,1,0,1]` it gives `[[0,1],[0],[1]]` which is hardly intended.

Comment: decorate-group-undecorate is unlikely to work very well with this problem. Consider the failing case of `[0,1,0,1]`, whether the last value should be grouped in with the previous or not depends not only on how it compares to the previous value, but also on how that value compares to the one before that - all the way back to the start of the list.

Comment: @Jonas Duregård Thanks for the points. The edge cases like empty or single element lists are easy fix. As for consequent alterations of `Ordering` type it might need further thinking in this case.

Comment: This is written in a rather odd style. The point-free `f <$> g <*> h` meaning `\ x -> f (g x) (h x)` is okay, although not something I’d present to a beginner. Other things to note: `zipWith (,)` can be simplified to `zip`; `groupBy (\ p c -> snd p == snd c)` can be written point-free as ``groupBy ((==) `on` snd)`` (where `on` is from `Data.Function`); and `groups >>= return . map fst` is more conventionally written `map fst <$> groups`, since `x >>= return . f` = `f <$> x`.

Comment: @Redu After edit `[0,0,1,0,-1]` still gives `[[0,0],[1],[0,-1]]`, no idea why it does that (gotta love QuickCheck). Also still missing the singleton case, `[0]` gives error (`tail []`).

Comment: @Jonas Duregård Has to make `squeeze` more clever but it's already my time off from office (beer time) so gotto do it later to night.

Comment: @Will Ness Your code is brilliant yet i think we both have got lost by overthinking. Sometimes it's much simpler than we have initially thought. Have a look at my last bit above, at the very end. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every ordered prefix is already in some order, and you don't care in which, as long as it is the longest:

```
import Data.List (group, unfoldr)

foo :: Ord t => [t] -> [[t]]
foo = unfoldr f
  where
  f []  = Nothing
  f [x] = Just ([x], [])
  f xs  = Just $ splitAt (length g + 1) xs
            where 
            (g : _) = group $ zipWith compare xs (tail xs)
```

---

`length` can be fused in to make the `splitAt` count in unary essentially, and thus not be as strict (unnecessarily, as Jonas Duregård rightly commented):

```
  ....
  f xs  = Just $ foldr c z g xs
            where 
            (g : _) = group $ zipWith compare xs (tail xs)
            c _ r (x:xs) = let { (a,b) = r xs } in (x:a, b)
            z     (x:xs) = ([x], xs)
```

Comment: Hell yeah..! Rockstar..! Took me like 20 minutes to get wtf you had in your mind. But then you are over and over running `g` on the remainder part of the list... Hmmm..! You already know that right..? I have another idea, which will eventually make me delete my answer.

Comment: @Redu Laziness should prevent any repeated comparisons, if that is what worries you (`head . group` is very lazy and doesn't touch most of the input list).

Comment: @Redu why delete? the more the merrier! :) It took some playing with the data, and observation at the REPL, to come up with this. the end result seems obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @Redu ... you meant,  running `splitAt (length g + 1)` over and over, where `g` is the first group. So `group` is used to find the longest prefix, and `splitAt` actually takes it out (or, splits it off).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether this question can be solve using foldr if splits and groups a list from

```
 [5,6,7,2,1,1,1]
```

to

```
 [[5,6,7],[2,1],[1,1]]
```

instead of

```
 [[5,6,7],[2],[1,1,1]]
```

The problem is in each step of foldr, we only know the sorted sub-list on right-hand side and a number to be processed. e.g. after read [1,1] of [5,6,7,2,1,1,1] and next step, we have

```
1, [[1, 1]]
```

There are no enough information to determine whether make a new group of 1 or group 1 to [[1,1]]

And therefore, we may construct required sorted sub-lists by reading elements of list from left to right, and why foldl to be used. Here is a solution without optimization of speed.

EDIT:
As the problems that @Jonas Duregård pointed out on comment, some redundant code has been removed, and beware that it is not a efficient solution.

```
splitSort::Ord a=>[a]->[[a]]
splitSort numList = foldl step [] numList
    where step [] n       = [[n]]
          step sublists n = groupSublist (init sublists) (last sublists) n

          groupSublist sublists [n1] n2 = sublists ++ [[n1, n2]]
          groupSublist sublists sortedList@(n1:n2:ns) n3
            | isEqual n1 n2 = groupIf (isEqual n2 n3) sortedList n3 
            | isAscen n1 n2 = groupIfNull isAscen sortedList n3
            | isDesce n1 n2 = groupIfNull isDesce sortedList n3
            | otherwise     = mkNewGroup sortedList n3
            where groupIfNull check sublist@(n1:n2:ns) n3
                    | null ns   = groupIf (check n2 n3) [n1, n2] n3
                    | otherwise = groupIf (check (last ns) n3) sublist n3
                  groupIf isGroup | isGroup   = addToGroup
                                  | otherwise = mkNewGroup
                  addToGroup gp n = sublists ++ [(gp ++ [n])]
                  mkNewGroup gp n = sublists ++ [gp] ++ [[n]]

          isEqual x y = x == y
          isAscen x y = x < y
          isDesce x y = x > y
```

Comment: If you clean this up a lot, you get the solution with all the reverses in my answer, but this one is less efficient (uses multiple ++ instead of a single reverse). You have a guard that checks `n1 == n2 || n1 < n2 || n1 > n2`, that whole expression can be replaced by True... Also you have large chunks of code that are identical except for the comparison operator - factor it out!

Comment: @Jonas Duregård Yes, the points you mentions above are right. It seems it can be to reverse whole list and all elements in sorted sub-list once after foldl construct the list.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution I am making the assumption that you want the "longest rally". By that I mean:

```
splitSort [0, 1, 0, 1] = [[0,1], [0,1]]    -- This is OK
splitSort [0, 1, 0, 1] = [[0,1], [0], [1]] -- This is not OK despite of fitting your requirements
```

Essentially, There are two pieces:

- Firstly, split the list in two parts: `(a, b)`. Part `a` is the longest rally considering the order of the two first elements. Part `b` is the rest of the list.
- Secondly, apply `splitSort` on `b` and put all list into one list of list

Taking the longest rally is surprisingly messy but straight. Given the list `x:y:xs`: by construction `x` and `y` will belong to the rally. The elements in `xs` belonging to the rally depends on whether or not they follow the `Ordering` of `x` and `y`. To check this point, you zip every element with the `Ordering` is has compared against its previous element and split the list when the `Ordering` changes. (edge cases are pattern matched) In code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

-- This function split the list in two (Longest Rally, Rest of the list)
splitSort' :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitSort'        []  = ([], [])
splitSort'     (x:[]) = ([x],[])
splitSort' l@(x:y:xs) = case span ( (o ==) . snd) $ zip (y:xs) relativeOrder of
                            (f, s) -> (x:map fst f, map fst s)
  where relativeOrder = zipWith compare (y:xs) l
        o = compare y x

-- This applies the previous recursively
splitSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
splitSort        []  = []
splitSort     (x:[]) = [[x]]
splitSort   (x:y:[]) = [[x,y]]
splitSort l@(x:y:xs) = fst sl:splitSort (snd sl)
  where sl = splitSort' l
```

Comment: This solution is equivalent to `splitSort2` in my previous answer. Note that it  probably runs in O(N^2) worst case time (unless the compiler uses some really clever trick to cancel out the zipping/unzipping), which seems a bit unfortunate for this clearly O(N) problem.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought looks like:

```
ordruns :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
ordruns = foldr extend []
  where
    extend a [                    ] = [      [a]      ]
    extend a (    [b]       : runs) =       [a,b]   : runs
    extend a (run@(b:c:etc) : runs)
      | compare a b == compare b c  =       (a:run) : runs
      | otherwise                   = [a] : run     : runs
```

This eagerly fills from the right, while maintaining the `Ordering` in all neighbouring pairs for each sublist. Thus only the first result can end up with a single item in it.

The thought process is this: an `Ordering` describes the three types of subsequence we're looking for: ascending `LT`, equal `EQ` or descending `GT`. Keeping it the same every time we add on another item means it will match throughout the subsequence. So we know we need to start a new run whenever the `Ordering` does not match. Furthermore, it's impossible to compare 0 or 1 items, so every run we create contains at least 1 and if there's only 1 we do add the new item.

We could add more rules, such as a preference for filling left or right. A reasonable optimization is to store the ordering for a sequence instead of comparing the leading two items twice per item. And we could also use more expressive types. I also think this version is inefficient (and inapplicable to infinite lists) due to the way it collects from the right; that was mostly so I could use cons (`:`) to build the lists.

Second thought: I could collect the lists from the left using plain recursion.

```
ordruns :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
ordruns [] = []
ordruns [a] = [[a]]
ordruns (a1:a2:as) = run:runs
  where
    runs = ordruns rest
    order = compare a1 a2
    run = a1:a2:runcontinuation
    (runcontinuation, rest) = collectrun a2 order as
    collectrun _ _ [] = ([], [])
    collectrun last order (a:as)
      | order == compare last a =
          let (more,rest) = collectrun a order as
          in (a:more, rest)
      | otherwise = ([], a:as)
```

More exercises. What if we build the list of comparisons just once, for use in grouping?

```
import Data.List

ordruns3 [] = []
ordruns3 [a] = [[a]]
ordruns3 xs = unfoldr collectrun marked
  where
    pairOrder = zipWith compare xs (tail xs)
    marked = zip (head pairOrder : pairOrder) xs
    collectrun [] = Nothing
    collectrun ((o,x):xs) = Just (x:map snd markedgroup, rest)
      where (markedgroup, rest) = span ((o==).fst) xs
```

And then there's the part where there's a `groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]` but no `groupOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]`. We can use a wrapper type to handle that.

```
import Data.List

data Grouped t = Grouped Ordering t
instance Eq (Grouped t) where
  (Grouped o1 _) == (Grouped o2 _) = o1 == o2
ordruns4 [] = []
ordruns4 [a] = [[a]]
ordruns4 xs = unmarked
  where
    pairOrder = zipWith compare xs (tail xs)
    marked = group $ zipWith Grouped (head pairOrder : pairOrder) xs
    unmarked = map (map (\(Grouped _ t) -> t)) marked
```

Of course, the wrapper type's test can be converted into a function to use `groupBy` instead:

```
import Data.List

ordruns5 [] = []
ordruns5 [a] = [[a]]
ordruns5 xs = map (map snd) marked
  where
    pairOrder = zipWith compare xs (tail xs)
    marked = groupBy (\a b -> fst a == fst b) $
               zip (head pairOrder : pairOrder) xs
```

These marking versions arrive at the same decoration concept Jonas Duregård applied.