# Fingertree head complexity

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, finger-tree

I was just reading [Apfelmus' excellent introduction to Finger Trees](https://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/monoid-fingertree.html) for the second time and started to wonder about his implementation of head:

```
import Prelude hiding (head)

data Tree v a = Leaf   v a
              | Branch v (Tree v a) (Tree v a)

toList :: Tree v a -> [a]
toList (Leaf _ a)     = [a]
toList (Branch _ x y) = toList x ++ toList y

head :: Tree v a -> a
head (Leaf _ a)     = a
head (Branch _ x _) = head x
```

As implementing functions in terms of one another is a quite nice way of reusing code, it got me thinking if the following implementation would be as efficient (complexity wise) as his original:

```
import Prelude -- not needed, just for making it obvious
data Tree v a = Leaf   v a
              | Branch v (Tree v a) (Tree v a) deriving Show

toList :: Tree v a -> [a]
toList (Leaf _ a)     = [a]
toList (Branch _ x y) = toList x ++ toList y

head' :: Tree v a -> a
head' = head . toList
```

Is lazy evaluation as efficient as the original implementation?

Comment: related: [Haskell foldl' poor performance with (++)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942678/849891), [Why are difference lists more efficient than regular concatenation in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13879260/849891), [Explicit Purely-Functional Data-Structure For Difference Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43941551/849891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `head` and `head'` should have the same time complexity if handed to GHC. I would expect a small constant-factor difference in favor of `head` (maybe 60% confident of this -- the list fusion optimization stuff is pretty wild when it works).

Comment: @FabianSchneider I have deleted that comment. It was due to sloppy thinking on my part. But to answer your question anyway: "space leak" means keeping something in memory even though it will demonstrably not be needed later.