# Folding list of trees - hasekell

Tags: haskell

I am working on this problem and got stumped hard.  The problem is posted on the picture below:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeXpF.png

Before it is marked as duplicate, someone has already answered this question but they changed the function definition to make their answer work. I've posted their solution here:

[Find Sum of leaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059220/find-sum-of-leaves)

I'm looking for an answer that would actually work with the function definition described in the question itself.

```
foldListTree :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> ListTree a -> a
```

I've attempted to do the solution as follows:

```
data ListTree a = ListLEAF [a] | ListNODE [(ListTree a)]
                  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

foldListTree :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> ListTree a -> a
foldListTree f base (ListLEAF a) = foldr f base a
foldListTree f base (ListNODE iL) = foldListTree f base (map f iL)
```

However I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `ListTree a' with actual type `[a -> a]'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this line:

```
foldListTree f base (ListNODE iL) = foldListTree f base (map f iL)
```

You have the following values available:

- `foldListTree :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> ListTree a -> a`
- `f            :: a -> (a -> a)`
- `base         :: a`
- `iL           :: [ListTree a]`

and you need to inhabit `a`.

Let's trace the type of your expression:

- `map   :: forall c d. (c -> d) -> ([c] -> [d])`
- `map f :: [a] -> [a -> a]`, where `c` is instantiated to `a` and `d` is instantiated to `a -> a`.

For the expression `map f iL` to be well-typed, `iL` should have type `[a]`, but it has type `[ListTree a]`. That's one type error, but not the one that the typechecker is reporting.

In the code `foldListTree f base (map f iL)`, the third parameter should have type `ListTree a`. However, `map f iL` has type `[a -> a]`.

What you actually want is:

```
foldListTree f base (ListNODE iL) = foldl' (foldListTree f) base iL
```

This is the derivation:

- `foldListTree                          :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> ListTree a -> a`
- `foldListTree f                        :: a -> ListTree a -> a`
- `foldl' (foldListTree f)         :: a -> [ListTree a] -> a`
- `foldl' (foldListTree f) base    :: [ListTree a] -> a`
- `foldl' (foldListTree f) base iL :: a`

Note that the question asks for the leaves to be visited from left to right. (If `f` is not commutative, the order that you visit the leaves matters.) In your base case, you've used `foldr`, but you should actually use `foldl` or `foldl'`. I use `foldl'` here because it avoids thunk buildup.

To use `foldl'`, you must import it:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
```

Update April 10, 2020: Update answer to use `foldl'` instead of `foldr`.

Comment: For flip, would it necessarily do this:  f foldListTree ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I understand you correctly, no, `f foldListTree` is definitely not the same thing as `flip $ foldListTree f`. Syntactically flipping the two names and writing `f foldListTree` means that you're calling `f` with `foldListTree` as an argument, which wouldn't typecheck. The expression `foldListTree f` is a function itself, and `flip` switches the order of its two arguments.