# Efficient string swapping in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve a problem for a functional programming exercise in Haskell. I have to implement a function such that, given a string with an even number of characters, the function returns the same string with character pairs swapped.

Like this:

"helloworld" -> "ehllworodl"

This is my current implementation:

```
swap :: String -> String
swap s = swapRec s ""
  where
    swapRec :: String -> String -> String
    swapRec [] result       = result
    swapRec (x:y:xs) result = swapRec xs (result++[y]++[x])
```

My function returns the correct results, however the programming exercise is timed, and It seems like my code is running too slowly.

Is there something I could do to make my code run faster, or I am following the wrong approach to the problem ?

Comment: Yes, don't use `(++)` since it takes *O(n)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. If you use [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-), then this takes linear time in the number of elements of the *first* list you want to concatenate. Since `result` can be large, this will result in a ineffeciency: the algorithm is then *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

You however do not *need* to construct the result with an accumulator. You can return a list, and do the processing of the remaining elements with a recursive call, like:

```
swap :: [a] -> [a]
swap [] = []
swap [x] = [x]
swap (x:y:xs) = y : x : swap xs
```

The above also uncovered a problem with the implementation: if the list had an odd length, then the function would have crashed. Here in the second case, we handle a list with one element by returning that list (perhaps you need to modify this according to the specifications).

Furthermore here we can benefit of Haskell's laziness: if we have a large list, want to pass it through the `swap` function, but are only interested in the first five elements, then we will *not* calculate the entire list.

We can also process all kinds of list with the above function: a list of numbers, of strings, etc.

Note that `(++)` itself is not *inherently* bad: if you need to concatenate, it is of course the most efficient way to do this. The problem is that you here in every recursive step will concatenate *again*, and the left list is growing each time.

Answer (score 3):

Affixing something at the end of the accumulator passed *into* a recursive call

```
    swapRec (x:y:xs) resultSoFar  =  swapRec xs 
         (resultSoFar ++ [y] ++ [x])
```

is the same as prepending it at the start of the result returned *from* the recursive call:

```
    swapRec (x:y:xs)  =  [y] ++ [x] ++ swapRec xs
```

You will have to amend your function accordingly throughout.

This is known as guarded recursion. What you were using is known as tail recursion (a *left* fold).

The added benefit is that it will now be *on-line* (i.e., taking *O(1)* time per each processed element). You were creating the `(++)` nesting on the *left* which leads to *quadratic* behaviour, as discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/849891).