# Faster way to create a list

Tags: list, haskell

I have to create a list of length `n` with the value `v` so I write

```
let lst = [v | _ <- [1..n]]
```

Is there a faster way because `n` may be huge?

Comment: What about `lst = replicate n v`. Note that even if `n` is gigantic, due to laziness, it will not construct the list, unless really necessary.

Comment: It is for an exercice, the list will be printed

Comment: `replicate` is the proper way however you may also do like `take n $ cycle [v]`

Comment: What have you done to determine that this is the performance bottleneck? (With 80% confidence: nothing yet, and if you do anything, you will discover it isn't.)

Comment: There were 10 tests, 3 failed because my code was too slow. I'm a newbie in Haskell and I was wondering how to improve the speed of the code. With **replicate**, it was still too slow, The major modification which solve the problem, was to put the result of replicate at the beginning of the list result instead of appending it at the end of the result, and to reverse the final result.

Comment: You could use Difference Lists for efficient appending if you have an append heavy work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/4543207

Comment: Well, I used difference_lists in Prolog, i didn't know their existence in Haskell. Thank you for the link !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can work with [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) which might be a bit faster:

```
let lst = replicate n v
```

but regardless how large `n` is, you here do not construct a list. Haskell is lazy, so that means that you it simply will store an "expression" to construct a list. If you are only interested in the second element, then it will not construct the rest of the list.

Note that due to [*list fusion* [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#how-rules-interact-with-class-methods), the compiler can sometimes rewrite the expression, such that the list is never constructed, and immediately consumed.

Comment: After improving the rest of the code  **replicate** help me to solve the exercice !, thank you.