# List comprehension in Haskell of any order or dimension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, monads, functor

Consider the following program.

```hs
chars = [" "] ++ ["A"] ++ ["B"] ++ (repeat "ABCD")

f :: Int -> [(Char,Int)]
f n = (,) <$> (chars !! n) <*> [1..3]

g :: Int -> [[(Char,Int)]]
g 1 = (\a     -> [a    ]) <$> (f 1)
g 2 = (\a b   -> [a,b  ]) <$> (f 1) <*> (f 2)
g 3 = (\a b c -> [a,b,c]) <$> (f 1) <*> (f 2) <*> (f 3)
-- g n = (\x1 x2 ... xn -> [x1,x2,...,xn]) <$> (f 1) <*> (f 2) <*> ... (f n)
```

How can we write `g n` generally for all n > 0, without typing out the expansion explicitly as above, ideally only using `Prelude` (and `Control.Applicative` if necessary)? Note that `f n = f (n-1)` for all n>3, hence it may be possible to define `g` recursively.

The output is like this (ignore the pretty printing):

```
> g 1
[ [ ( 'A' , 1 ) ] , [ ( 'A' , 2 ) ] , [ ( 'A' , 3 ) ] ]

> g 2
[ [ ( 'A' , 1 ) , ( 'B' , 1 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 1 ) , ( 'B' , 2 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 1 ) , ( 'B' , 3 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 2 ) , ( 'B' , 1 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 2 ) , ( 'B' , 2 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 2 ) , ( 'B' , 3 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 3 ) , ( 'B' , 1 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 3 ) , ( 'B' , 2 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 3 ) , ( 'B' , 3 ) ]
]

> g 3
[ [ ( 'A' , 1 ) , ( 'B' , 1 ) , ( 'A' , 1 ) ]
, [ ( 'A' , 1 ) , ( 'B' , 1 ) , ( 'A' , 2 ) ]
...
, [ ( 'A' , 3 ) , ( 'B' , 3 ) , ( 'D' , 3 ) ]
]
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but practically, do you really *need* to handle all `n > 0`? At `n = 10` there's going to be close to 4 billion elements in that list. At `n = 15`, there's going to be almost 1E+15 elements.

Comment: As written, `f i` returns the same value for all `i >= 3`.

Comment: I am writing a solver for a 2D "rubik's" cube game with this. It should be possible to solve it/strategically simplify the solution process with group theory. Here I am brute-forcing a group that swaps 1 with 2. Hopefully it doesn't require over `n>8`. Game here: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/twiddle.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g n = traverse f [1 .. n]
```

`traverse` is in the Prelude (at least for the last few years).

As that's a bit non-obvious, here's how I got there:

1. I noticed you were applying `f` to the numbers from 1 to n, so I started with `map f [1 .. n]`.
2. This produced a `[[(Char, Int)]]`, which is the desired result type, but it needs to be sort of...  turned sideways and multiplied. You want all the lists that come from non-deterministic selection of values in the inner lists.  Non-deterministic selection is the essence of the `Applicative` instance for `[]`, and it turns out that `sequence` on something of type `[[a]]` is exactly the operation "produce all the lists you get from combinatorially combining elements from the inner lists". This got me to `sequence $ map f [1 .. n]`.
3. But the pair of `sequence` and `map` is common enough that there's an operation that does both at once. `sequence . map f` === `traverse f`.  So applying that rule simplified the result.  `traverse f [1 .. n]`.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this. This is way better than my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I played with the list of `Prelude` functions, including both `sequence` and `traverse` (and some others), but didn't have the insight to see something that simple!

Comment: `(sequence .) . map` is `mapM` actually, which is a clearer name (IMO:YMMV), way shorter to type, and `[]` is a Monad anyway. :)

Comment: (what I forgot to add is that it's with `sequenceA` that it's `traverse` -- what you undoubtedly know, but I note this for the sake of a casual traveler).

Answer (score 1):

```
g n = mapM f [1..n]
```

### How to get there.

Your examples are equivalently written with List Comprehension syntax as

```
g :: Int -> [[(Char,Int)]]
g 1 = [[a    ] | a <- (f 1)]
g 2 = [[a,b  ] | a <- (f 1), b <- (f 2)]
g 3 = [[a,b,c] | a <- (f 1), b <- (f 2), c <- (f 3)]
-- g n = [[a,b,c, ... , z] | a <- (f 1), b <- (f 2), ... , z <- (f n)]
```

which is exactly how `sequence` is defined, in Monad Comprehension syntax:

```
sequence [as,bs,cs, ... , zs] = [[a,b,c, ... , z] | a <- as, b <- bs, ... , z <- zs]
```

and thus

```
g n = sequence [(f 1), (f 2), ... , (f n)]
    = sequence $ map f [1..n]
```

which is, in its turn, the definition (or an equivalent thereof) of `mapM`.

(`mapM` is also known as `traverse` now, for types which are also Applicatives, as well as Monads. Haskell lists `[]` are both, anyway, and I find the name `mapM` clearer and shorter to type).

---

This has been a public service announcement in favor of the underappreciated List Comprehension and Monad Comprehension syntax.

I'm actually fine with `g n = sequence $ map f [1..n]`, and don't feel any particular urge to shorten it any further, as I find it clearer than both alternatives.

Comment: I did start with the list comprehension syntax as yours, and slowly made my way into the `<*>` syntax, and was thinking of something like `fmap (.) fmap` composition to conjure up `a <*> b <*> ...` but couldn't get it to work. Anyway, thx for the explanation!

Comment: you're most welcome. :) the applicative syntax `...<$>...<*>...<*>...` comes as a substitute for the missing general `liftAn`, and MonadComprehensions can be another alternative for that (the *brackety* syntax; as in the original paper). What's missing is the ability for MonadComprehension to be translated as an Applicative-based code, when possible. I have [several posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+essentially+Monadic) about what makes a computation *essentially* Monadic.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
g 0 = [[]]
g n = (\xs x -> xs ++ [x]) <$> g (n - 1) <*> f n
```

Or more complicated, but also more efficient:

```
g = map ($ []) . go
  where
    go :: Int -> [[(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]]
    go 0 = [id]
    go n = (\xs x -> xs . (x:)) <$> go (n - 1) <*> f n
```

This uses Hughes lists/difference lists to avoid [the quadratic slowdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/849891) of `\xs x -> xs ++ [x]`.

Comment: I did try using `++` in the lambda, but couldn't quite get the recurrent definition of g with itself. Thanks!

Comment: there's also the simpler option of `g = map reverse . g'
        where {
        g' 0 = [[]] ;
        g' n = [ (x:xs) | xs <- g' (n-1), x <- f n ] }` which might even be a little bit more performant that Hughes', if the latter isn't used with `(\xs x ys -> xs $! (x:ys))` instead of (the equivalent of) `(\xs x ys -> xs ((x:) ys))` -- unless GHC is smart enough to do this on its own. (or maybe I'm way off the mark here; and actually it's all just about the `~ 2n` time vs the `~ 3n` time, so, not that significant anyway :) )