# Compression reverse Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this function where i compress a string

```
compression :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
compression str = map (\lt -> (head lt, length lt)) (group str)
```

I've tried to edit this into it's reverse

EXAMPLE:

```hs
revcompression [('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 4), ('b', 1)] ==  "aabbbccccb"
```

Can anyone edit the first one into the reverse?

Comment: You should show what you've tried and where you're stuck. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @NoNameDRR if your problem is solved, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is without recursion:

```hs
decompress :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decompress xs = concat $ map (\(c, n) -> replicate n c) xs
```

Or using `>>=`:

```hs
decompress :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decompress xs = xs >>= (\(c, n) -> replicate n c)
```

Or point-free:

```
decompress :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decompress = flip (>>=) (uncurry replicate . swap)
  where swap (a, b) = (b,a)
```

Or with the imports suggested in the comments:

```hs
import Control.Monad ((=<<))
import Data.Tuple (swap)

decompress :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decompress = (=<<) (uncurry replicate . swap)
```

the joys of haskell :)

Comment: Note that `swap` is already defined in `Data.Tuple`.

Comment: And `(=<<) == flip (>>=)` is defined in `Control.Monad`.

Comment: we can use `(uncurry (flip replicate) =<<)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with recursion using the [`replicate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) function, which will repeat an element a certain number of times:

```hs
decompress :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
decompress [] = ... -- what should you get when you decompress the empty array?
decompress ((c, n):xs) = replicate n c ++ ... -- hint: you'll want to have a recursive call
```

Where the `...` is something you need to fill in.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i need without recursion, only map filter zipWith etc...

Answer (score 0):

Jut play with some example data, and *generalize*:

```
compressed str = map (\lt -> (head lt, length lt)) (group str)

compressed [a,a,a,b,b,b,c,d,d,a] =
  = map (head &&& length) [ [a,a,a], [b,b,b], [c], [d,d], [a] ]
  = [ (a, 3), (b, 3), (c, 1), (d, 2), (a, 1)]

uncompressed cs@[ (a, 3), (b, 3), (c, 1), (d, 2), (a, 1)] =
  = concat [ [a,a,a], [b,b,b], [c], [d,d], [a] ]
  = concat [ replicate k x | (x,k) <- cs ]
  = concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate)) cs
```

Indeed,

```
> :t concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate))
concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate)) :: [(b, Int)] -> [b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```hs
compression :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
compression str = map (\lt -> (head lt, length lt)) (group str)
```

So you basically need a function that reverses the operations done in `compression`.

The type of that function(say `decompression`) will be `[(Char, Int)] -> String` and it will go through a list of tuples and populate a list with the first tuple member the number of times determined by the second tuple member. One simple way to do it would be a `fold` as follows:

```hs
decompression = foldl (\acc (a, n) -> acc ++ (replicate n a)) []
```

A fold uses recursion implicitly and we are also using a handy function `replicate` to make our work easier. There are other, perhaps more elegant way to do it in the other answers, I think using a `fold` is pretty readable and natural.

EDIT : As pointed out by @Will Ness in a comment below. Using `++` in a left associated chain is an antipattern. It's quite inefficient as explained in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/11728033). So it's better to use `foldr` instead as it is right-associative.

```hs
decompression = foldr (\(a, n) acc -> (replicate n a) ++ acc) []
```

Comment: left-associated `++` chain [is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/849891), unfortunately. but you could use `foldr`, then the `++`s would get grouped on the right, and that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You've already been provided with various solutions. I'll try to provide some insight on how to go about finding one such solution. Below we will derive the solution provided by @rethab,

```
decompress xs = concat $ map (\(c, n) -> replicate n c) xs
```

or more succinctly,

```
decompress = concat . map (\(c, n) -> replicate n c)
```

---

In what follows we will write `f'` to denote a left inverse of `f`, i.e. a function such that `f' . f = id`. The two following properties hold,

- `f' . g'` is a left inverse of `g . f`
- `map f'` is a left inverse of `map f`

The original compress function can be written as,

```
headLen lt = (head lt, length lt)
compression str = map headLen . group
```

We are looking for a function `decompress = compress'`. Given the two properties above, if we have `group'` and  `headLen'` then a solution would be,

```
decompression = group' . map headLen'
```

So we've factored the original problem into two smaller ones. Finding a left inverse of `group` and a left inverse of `headLen`. These are rather simple,

```
group' = concat
headLen' (c, n) = replicate n c
```

and so we have,

```
decompression = concat . map (\(c, n) -> replicate n c)
```