# How can I fix my replace haskell function?

Tags: haskell, replace

It eill work when  : replace :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a] will be. How can I convert az a to an [a] in my code ?

```
replace :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace _ _ [] = []
replace a x (y:ys)
 | a == y = x : replace a x ys
 | otherwise = y : replace a x ys
```

```
Example:

replace '?' "a" "" == ""
replace 'a' "e" "alma" == "elme"
replace 'a' "e" "nincsbenne" == "nincsbenne"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong operator for the first guard (`a == y`) - `:` is used to  prepend a head element to a list but `x` is a list not a single element, so you need to use `++` which concatenates two lists (`x` and one returned by recursive call):

```hs
replace :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace _ _ [] = []
replace a x (y:ys)
 | a == y = x ++ replace a x ys -- ++ instead of :
 | otherwise = y : replace a x ys
```

Related - [Haskell (:) and (++) differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817891/2501279)